# Delete all but the most recent X files in bash

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

Is there a simple way, in a pretty standard UNIX environment with bash, to run a command to delete all but the most recent X files from a directory?

To give a bit more of a concrete example, imagine some cron job writing out a file (say, a log file or a tar-ed up backup) to a directory every hour. I'd like a way to have another cron job running which would remove the oldest files in that directory until there are less than, say, 5.

And just to be clear, there's only one file present, it should never be deleted.

Answer (score 198, accepted):

The problems with the existing answers:

- inability to handle filenames with embedded spaces or newlines.

  - in the case of solutions that invoke `rm` directly on an unquoted command substitution (`` rm `...` ``), there's an added risk of unintended globbing.
- inability to distinguish between files and directories (i.e., if *directories* happened to be among the 5 most recently modified filesystem items, you'd effectively retain *fewer* than 5 files, and applying `rm` to directories will fail).

[wnoise's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299911/45375) addresses these issues, but the solution is *GNU*-specific (and quite complex).

Here's a pragmatic, **POSIX-compliant solution** that comes with only **one caveat**: it cannot handle filenames with embedded *newlines* - but I don't consider that a real-world concern for most people.

<sup>For the record, here's the explanation for why it's generally not a good idea to parse `ls` output: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs</sup>

```
ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6 | xargs -I {} rm -- {}
```

<sup>Note: This command operates in the ***current* directory**; to **target a directory *explicitly*, use a subshell (`(...)`) with `cd`**:

`(cd /path/to && ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6 | xargs -I {} rm -- {})`

The same **applies analogously to the commands below**.</sup>

The above is **inefficient**, because `xargs` has to invoke `rm` separately *for each filename*.
However, your platform's specific `xargs` implementation may allow you to solve this problem:

---

A solution that **works with *GNU* `xargs`** is to use **`-d '\n'`**, which makes `xargs` consider each input line a separate argument, yet passes as many arguments as will fit on a command line *at once*:

```
ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6 | xargs -d '\n' -r rm --
```

<sup>Note: Option `-r` (`--no-run-if-empty`) ensures that `rm` is not invoked if there's *no input*.</sup>

A solution that **works with *both* *GNU* `xargs` *and* *BSD* `xargs`** (including on **macOS**) - though technically still *not* POSIX-compliant - is to use **`-0`** to handle `NUL`-separated input, after first translating newlines to `NUL` (`0x0`) chars., which also passes (typically) all filenames *at once*:

```
ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm --
```

**Explanation:**

- `ls -tp` prints the names of filesystem items sorted by how recently they were modified , in descending order (most recently modified items first) (`-t`), with directories printed with a trailing `/` to mark them as such (`-p`).

  - Note: It is the fact that `ls -tp` always outputs file / directory *names* only, not full paths, that necessitates the subshell approach mentioned above for targeting a directory other than the current one (`(cd /path/to && ls -tp ...)`).
- `grep -v '/$'` then weeds out directories from the resulting listing, by omitting (`-v`) lines that have a trailing `/` (`/$`).

  - *Caveat*: Since a *symlink that points to a directory* is technically not itself a directory, such symlinks will *not* be excluded.
- `tail -n +6` skips the first *5* entries in the listing, in effect returning all *but* the 5 most recently modified files, if any.
  Note that in order to exclude `N` files, `N+1` must be passed to `tail -n +`.
- `xargs -I {} rm -- {}` (and its variations) then invokes on `rm` on all these files; if there are no matches at all, `xargs` won't do anything.

  - `xargs -I {} rm -- {}` defines placeholder `{}` that represents each input line *as a whole*, so `rm` is then invoked once for each input line, but with filenames with embedded spaces handled correctly.
  - `--` in all cases ensures that any filenames that happen to start with `-` aren't mistaken for *options* by `rm`.

---

A **variation** on the original problem, **in case the matching files need to be processed *individually* or *collected in a shell array***:

```
# One by one, in a shell loop (POSIX-compliant):
ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6 | while IFS= read -r f; do echo "$f"; done

# One by one, but using a Bash process substitution (<(...), 
# so that the variables inside the `while` loop remain in scope:
while IFS= read -r f; do echo "$f"; done < <(ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6)

# Collecting the matches in a Bash *array*:
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra files  < <(ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6)
printf '%s\n' "${files[@]}" # print array elements
```

Comment: Certainly better than most other answers here, so I'm happy to lend my support, even inasmuch as I consider ignoring the newline case to be a thing to be done only with caution.

Comment: If you do `ls` not in the current directory, then the paths to files will contain '/', which means that `grep -v '/'` won't match anything.  I believe `grep -v '/$'` is what you want to only exclude directories.

Comment: @waldol1: Thanks; I've updated the answer to include your suggestion, which also makes the `grep` command conceptually clearer. Note, however, that the problem you describe would _not_ have surfaced with a single directory path; e.g., `ls -p /private/var` would still only print mere filenames. Only if you passed _multiple_ file arguments (typically via a glob) would you see actual paths in the output; e.g., `ls -p /private/var/*` (and you'd also see the contents of matching subdirectories, unless you also included `-d`).

Comment: These commands work on files in the current directory. I wanted to run the above BSD command on files in another directory... /mnt/usb/openwrt. I adapted `ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm --` to this-> `ls -tp /mnt/usb/openwrt | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6 | sed 's|^|/mnt/usb/openwrt/|' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm --`

Comment: @FlexMcMurphy, it occurred to me that using a subshell (`(...)`) with `cd` is simpler and more robust: `(cd /mnt/usb/openwrt && ls -tp | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +6 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 rm --)` - I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Very nice thanks for sharing and for the detailed explainations 

Comment: I'm glad to hear the answer is helpful, @tchartron, and thanks for the nice feedback.

Answer (score 124):

Remove all but 5 (or whatever number) of the most recent files in a directory.

```
rm `ls -t | awk 'NR>5'`
```

Comment: I needed this to only consider my archive files. change `ls -t` to `ls -td *.bz2`

Comment: I used this for directories by changing it to rm -rf `ls -t | awk 'NR>1'` (I only wanted the most recent).

Thanks!

Comment: `ls -t | awk 'NR>5' | xargs rm -f`   if you prefer pipes and you need to suppress the error if there is nothing to be deleted.

Comment: Strangle enough this did not work for me. I had to use @H2ONaCl's xargs version

Comment: Concise and readable, perhaps, but dangerous to use; if trying to delete a file created with `touch 'hello * world'`, this would delete **absolutely everything in the current directory**.

Comment: Even though this was answered in 2008 it works like a charm and just what I needed to simply delete old backups from a specific directory. Awesome.

Comment: I wanted to give an explicit path here.

Comment: ***WARNING*** Please make sure you run this from the directory that files are going to be deleted from! I stupidly ran this from a working code directory of 100 files or so and it zapped the f*&$*ing lot!! Fortunately I had just taken a backup 30 mins before (Phew!) (You know that sinking feeling you get when your heart stops and you cant find the files in the trash bin)

Answer (score 89):

```
(ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u|xargs rm
```

This version supports names with spaces:

```
(ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u|sed -e 's,.*,"&",g'|xargs rm
```

Comment: This command will not correctly handle files with spaces in the names.

Comment: To fix above use: `(ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u|sed -e 's,.*,"&",g'|xargs rm`

Comment: This one fails if there are no files to delete.

Comment: @Mantas I think that can be solved using `rm -f` (I have only tried `-rf` though, dunno if it works without -r).

Comment: `(ls -t|head -n 5;ls)` is a [command group](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#PARENSREF). It prints the 5 most recent files twice. `sort` puts identical lines together. `uniq -u` removes duplicates, so that all but the 5 most recent files remains. `xargs rm` calls `rm` on each of them.

Comment: `(ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u|sed -e 's,.*,"&",g'|xargs rm -rf` works for:
1) deleting directories
2) avoiding "rm: missing operand" when there is nothing to delete

Comment: Doesn't work for files like "-000-"

`(ls -t|head -n 100;ls)|sort|uniq -u | xargs printf './%s\n' | xargs rm` works in my case.

Comment: @Matas is correct. it doesn't work if you have less then 5 files in folder, be careful

Comment: This deletes all your files if you have 5 or less! Add `--no-run-if-empty` to `xargs` as in `(ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u|xargs --no-run-if-empty rm` please update the answer.

Comment: Echo Gonfi, this removes the oldest 5 files. That is NOT even remotely the same thing as keeping the newest 5 files.

Comment: Even the one that "supports names with spaces" is dangerous. Consider a name that contains literal quotes: `touch 'foo " bar'` will throw off the whole rest of the command.

Comment: ...it's safer to use `xargs -d $'\n'` than to inject quotes into your content, though NUL-delimiting the input stream (which requires using something other than `ls` to *really* do right) is the ideal option.

Comment: Why not `ls -t | tail -n +6` instead of `(ls -t|head -n 5;ls)|sort|uniq -u`?

Answer (score 73):

Simpler variant of thelsdj's answer:

```
ls -tr | head -n -5 | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm
```

`ls -tr` displays all the files, oldest first (`-t` newest first, `-r` reverse).

`head -n -5` displays all but the 5 last lines (ie the 5 newest files).

`xargs rm` calls `rm` for each selected file.

Comment: Need to add --no-run-if-empty to xargs so that it doesn't fail when there are fewer than 5 files.

Comment: ls -1tr | head -n -5 | xargs rm   <---------- you need to add a -1 to the ls or you won't get a list output for head to properly work against

Comment: @AlJoslin, `-1` is default when output is to a pipeline, so it isn't mandatory here. This has much larger issues, related to default behavior of `xargs` when parsing names with spaces, quotes, &c.

Comment: seems that the `--no-run-if-empty` isn't recognized in my shell. I'm using Cmder on windows.

Comment: Might need to use the `-0` option if filenames could contain whitespaces.  Haven't tested it yet though.  [source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16758525/3006854)

Answer (score 20):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -r -z -n | awk 'BEGIN { RS="\0"; ORS="\0"; FS="" } NR > 5 { sub("^[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)? ", ""); print }' | xargs -0 rm -f
```

Requires GNU find for -printf, and GNU sort for -z, and GNU awk for "\0", and GNU xargs for -0, but handles files with embedded newlines or spaces.

Comment: If you want to remove directories, just change the -f to a -d and add a -r to the rm.


find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -r -z -n | awk 'BEGIN { RS="\0"; ORS="\0"; FS="" } NR > 5 { sub("^[0-9]*(.[0-9]*)? ", ""); print }' | xargs -0 rm -rf

Comment: At a glance, I'm surprised at the complexity (or, for that matter, necessity) of the `awk` logic. Am I missing some requirements inside the OP's question that make it necessary?

Comment: @Charles Duffy: The sub() removes the timestamp, which is what is sorted on.  The timestamp produced by "%T@" may include a fraction part.  Splitting on space with FS breaks paths with embedded spaces.  I suppose removing up through first space works, but is nearly as difficult to read.  The RS and ORS separators can't be set on the command line, because they are NULs.

Comment: @wnoise, my usual approach to this is to pipe into a shell `while read -r -d ' '; IFS= -r -d ''; do ...` loop -- the first read terminates on the space, while the second goes on to the NUL.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: I'm always leery of raw shell, perhaps due to byzantine quoting concerns.  I now think GNU `sed -z -e 's/[^ ]* //; 1,5d'` is the clearest. (or perhaps `sed -n -z -e 's/[^ ]* //; 6,$p'`.

Comment: I'd argue that the quoting isn't so bad once one understands the execution model, but will grant that having previously made that investment it's hard for me to gauge what it would look like were it not in the mists of the past.

Answer (score 16):

All these answers fail when there are directories in the current directory. Here's something that works:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | xargs -x ls -t | awk 'NR>5' | xargs -L1 rm
```

This:

1. works when there are directories in the current directory
2. tries to remove each file even if the previous one couldn't be removed (due to permissions, etc.)
3. fails safe when the number of files in the current directory is excessive and `xargs` would normally screw you over (the `-x`)
4. doesn't cater for spaces in filenames (perhaps you're using the wrong OS?)

Comment: What happens if `find` returns more filenames than can be passed on a single command line to `ls -t`? (Hint: You get multiple runs of `ls -t`, each of which is only individually sorted, rather than having a globally-correct sort order; thus, this answer is badly broken when running with sufficiently large directories).

Answer (score 14):

```
ls -tQ | tail -n+4 | xargs rm
```

List filenames by modification time, quoting each filename. Exclude first 3 (3 most recent). Remove remaining.

EDIT after helpful comment from mklement0 (thanks!): corrected -n+3 argument, and note this will not work as expected if filenames contain newlines and/or the directory contains subdirectories.

Comment: The ``-Q`` option doesn't seem to exist on my machine.

Comment: Hmm, the option has been in GNU core utils for ~20 years, but is not mentioned in BSD variants. Are you on a mac?

Comment: I am indeed. Didn't think there was differences for this kind of really basic commands between up-to-date systems. Thanks for your answer !

Comment: @Mark: ++ for `-Q`. Yes, `-Q` is a GNU extension (here's the [POSIX `ls` spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ls.html)). A small caveat (rarely a problem in practice): `-Q` encodes embedded _newlines_ in filenames as literal `\n`, which `rm` won't recognize. To exclude the first _3_, the `xargs` argument must `+4`. Finally, a caveat that applies to most other answers too: your command will only work as intended if there are no _subdirectories_ in the current dir.

Comment: How can I run this between `then` and `fi` in the same line

Comment: When there is nothing to remove, you have call xargs with `--no-run-if-empty` option : `ls -tQ | tail -n+4 | xargs --no-run-if-empty rm`

Answer (score 8):

Ignoring newlines is ignoring security and good coding. wnoise had the only good answer. Here is a variation on his that puts the filenames in an array $x

```
while IFS= read -rd ''; do 
    x+=("${REPLY#* }"); 
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -r -z -n )
```

Comment: I'd suggest clearing `IFS` -- otherwise you'd risk losing trailing whitespace from filenames. Can scope that to the read command: `while IFS= read -rd ''; do`

Comment: why `"${REPLY#* }"`?

Answer (score 8):

**For Linux** (GNU tools), an efficient & robust way to keep the `n` newest files in the current directory while removing the rest:

```bash
n=5

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%T@ %p\0' |
sort -z -nrt ' ' -k1,1 |
sed -z -e "1,${n}d" -e 's/[^ ]* //' |
xargs -0r rm -f --
```

---

**For BSD**, `find` doesn't have the `-printf` predicate, `stat` can't output NULL bytes, and `sed` + `awk` can't handle `NULL`-delimited records.

Here's a solution that **doesn't support newlines in paths** but that safeguards against them by filtering them out:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
n=5

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -path $'*\n*' -exec stat -f '%.9Fm %N' {} + |
sort -nrt ' ' -k1,1 |
awk -v n="$n" -F'^[^ ]* ' 'NR > n {printf "%s%c", $2, 0}' |
xargs -0 rm -f --
```

<sup>**note:** I'm using `bash` because of the `$'\n'` notation. For `sh` you can define a variable containing a literal newline and use it instead.</sup>

---

**POSIX** solution (inspired from @mklement0 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862475/3387716)).

This one adds the correct escaping for POSIX `xargs`, but it would still break when a file or directory contains a linefeed in the name; if you want to handle that then there's no other choice than purging or renaming those files.

```bash
n=5

ls -tp . |
grep -v '/$' |
head -n +"$((n+1))" |
sed -e 's/"/"\\""/g' -e 's/.*/"&"/' |
xargs rm --
```

**remark:** In fact you can replace the `grep | head | sed` with `awk -v n="$n" '/[^/]$/ && --n < 0 {gsub(/"/, "\"\\\\\"\""); print "\"" $0 "\""}'`

---

Solution for **UNIX & Linux** (inspired from AIX/HP-UX/SunOS/BSD/Linux `ls -b`):

Some platforms don't provide `find -printf`, nor `stat`, nor support `NUL`-delimited records with `stat`/`sort`/`awk`/`sed`/`xargs`. That's why using `perl` is probably the most portable way to tackle the problem, because it is available by default in almost every OS.

I could have written the whole thing in `perl` but I didn't. I only use it for substituting `stat` and for encoding-decoding-escaping the filenames. The core logic is the same as the previous solutions and is implemented with POSIX tools.

**note:** `perl`'s default `stat` has a resolution of a second, but starting from `perl-5.8.9` you can get sub-second resolution with the `stat` function of the module `Time::HiRes` (when both the OS and the filesystem support it). That's what I'm using here; if your `perl` doesn't provide it then you can remove the `‑MTime::HiRes=stat` from the command line.

```bash
n=5

find . '(' -name '.' -o -prune ')' -type f -exec \
perl -MTime::HiRes=stat -le '
    foreach (@ARGV) {
        @st = stat($_);
        if ( @st > 0 ) {
            s/([\\\n])/sprintf( "\\%03o", ord($1) )/ge;
            print sprintf( "%.9f %s", $st[9], $_ );
        }
        else { print STDERR "stat: $_: $!"; }
    }
' {} + |

sort -nrt ' ' -k1,1 |

sed -e "1,${n}d" -e 's/[^ ]* //' |

perl -l -ne '
    s/\\([0-7]{3})/chr(oct($1))/ge;
    s/(["\n])/"\\$1"/g;
    print "\"$_\""; 
' |

xargs -E '' sh -c '[ "$#" -gt 0 ] && rm -f -- "$@"' sh
```

**Explanations:**

- For each file found, the first `perl` gets the modification time and outputs it along the encoded filename (each `newline` and `backslash` characters are replaced with the literals `\012` and `\134` respectively).
- Now each `time filename` is guaranteed to be single-line, so POSIX `sort` and `sed` can safely work with this stream.
- The second `perl` decodes the filenames and escapes them for POSIX `xargs`.
- Lastly, `xargs` calls `rm` for deleting the files. The `sh` command is a trick that prevents `xargs` from running `rm` when there's no files to delete.

Comment: ++ed for the much more robust solution than the accepted answer (posted in good old days) with a modern practical style.

Comment: @tshiono, the only thing the [previously accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34862475/45375) doesn't handle correctly (as stated) is _newlines in filenames_, which is hardly a real-world problem. On the plus side, it is much more concise and conceptually simpler.

Comment: @mklement0, ...hardly a _common_ real-world problem, maybe, but uncommon real-world problems are still real-world problems. When I'm wearing my red-team hat, creating deliberately unhandled conditions is something attackers _do_; when I'm wearing my defensive-coding hat, having random binary garbage dumped into a filename is something I've seen in my career (due to a 100% unintentional bug), with catastrophic results when that garbage was poorly-handled.

Answer (score 5):

I realize this is an old thread, but maybe someone will benefit from this. This command will find files in the current directory :

```
for F in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*_srv_logs_*.tar.gz" -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -r -z -n | tail -n+5 | awk '{ print $2; }'); do rm $F; done
```

This is a little more robust than some of the previous answers as it allows to limit your search domain to files matching expressions. First, find files matching whatever conditions you want. Print those files with the timestamps next to them.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*_srv_logs_*.tar.gz" -printf '%T@ %p\n'
```

Next, sort them by the timestamps:

```
sort -r -z -n
```

Then, knock off the 4 most recent files from the list:

```
tail -n+5
```

Grab the 2nd column (the filename, not the timestamp):

```
awk '{ print $2; }'
```

And then wrap that whole thing up into a for statement:

```
for F in $(); do rm $F; done
```

This may be a more verbose command, but I had much better luck being able to target conditional files and execute more complex commands against them.

Answer (score 4):

If the filenames don't have spaces, this will work:

```
ls -C1 -t| awk 'NR>5'|xargs rm
```

If the filenames do have spaces, something like

```
ls -C1 -t | awk 'NR>5' | sed -e "s/^/rm '/" -e "s/$/'/" | sh
```

Basic logic:

- get a listing of the files in time order, one column
- get all but the first 5 (n=5 for this example)
- first version: send those to rm
- second version: gen a script that will remove them properly

Comment: Don't forget the `while read` trick for dealing with spaces:

`ls -C1 -t | awk 'NR>5' | while read d ; do rm -rvf "$d" ; done`

Comment: @pinkeen, not quite safe as given there. `while IFS= read -r d` would be a bit better -- the `-r` prevents backslash literals from being consumed by `read`, and the `IFS=` prevents automatic trimming of trailing whitespace.

Comment: BTW, if one is worried about hostile filenames, this is an **extremely** dangerous approach. Consider a file created with `touch $'hello \'$(rm -rf ~)\' world'`; the literal quotes inside the filename would counter the literal quotes you're adding with `sed`, resulting in the code within the filename being executed.

Comment: (to be clear, the "this" above was referring to the `| sh` form, which is the one with the shell injection vulnerability).

Answer (score 3):

With zsh

Assuming you don't care about present directories and you will not have more than 999 files (choose a bigger number if you want, or create a while loop).

```
[ 6 -le `ls *(.)|wc -l` ] && rm *(.om[6,999])
```

In `*(.om[6,999])`, the `.` means files, the `o` means sort order up, the `m` means by date of modification (put `a` for access time or `c` for inode change), the `[6,999]` chooses a range of file, so doesn't rm the 5 first.

Comment: Intriguing, but for the life of me I couldn't get the sorting glob qualifier (`om`) to work (any sorting I've tried showed no effect - neither on OSX 10.11.2 (tried with zsh 5.0.8 and 5.1.1), nor on Ubuntu 14.04 (zsh 5.0.2)) - what am I missing?. As for the range endpoint: no need to hard-code it, simply use `-1` to refer to the last entry and thus include all remaining files: `[6,-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Adaptation of @mklement0's excellent answer with some parameters and without needing to navigate to the folder containing the files to be deleted...

```
TARGET_FOLDER="/my/folder/path"
FILES_KEEP=5
ls -tp "$TARGET_FOLDER"**/* | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +$((FILES_KEEP+1)) | xargs -d '\n' -r rm --
```

[Ref(s).: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3572628/3223785 ]

**Thanks!**

Comment: This doesn't properly exclude directories though

Answer (score 1):

found interesting cmd in Sed-Onliners - Delete last 3 lines - fnd it perfect for another way to skin the cat (okay not) but idea:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # sed cmd chng #2 to value file wish to retain

 cd /opt/depot 

 ls -1 MyMintFiles*.zip > BigList
 sed -n -e :a -e '1,2!{P;N;D;};N;ba' BigList > DeList

 for i in `cat DeList` 
 do 
 echo "Deleted $i" 
 rm -f $i  
 #echo "File(s) gonzo " 
 #read junk 
 done 
 exit 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Removes all but the 10 latest (most recents) files

```
ls -t1 | head -n $(echo $(ls -1 | wc -l) - 10 | bc) | xargs rm
```

If less than 10 files no file is removed and you will have :
error head: illegal line count -- 0

[To count files with bash](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x700.html)

Answer (score 1):

I needed an elegant solution for the busybox (router), all xargs or array solutions were useless to me - no such command available there. find and mtime is not the proper answer as we are talking about 10 items and not necessarily 10 days. Espo's answer was the shortest and cleanest and likely the most unversal one.

Error with spaces and when no files are to be deleted are both simply solved the standard way:

```
rm "$(ls -td *.tar | awk 'NR>7')" 2>&-
```

Bit more educational version: We can do it all if we use awk differently. Normally, I use this method to pass (return) variables from the awk to the sh. As we read all the time that can not be done, I beg to differ: here is the method.

Example for .tar files with no problem regarding the spaces in the filename. To test, replace "rm" with the "ls".

```
eval $(ls -td *.tar | awk 'NR>7 { print "rm \"" $0 "\""}')
```

Explanation:

`ls -td *.tar` lists all .tar files sorted by the time. To apply to all the files in the current folder, remove the "d *.tar" part

`awk 'NR>7...` skips the first 7 lines

`print "rm \"" $0 "\""` constructs a line: rm "file name"

`eval` executes it

Since we are using `rm`, I would not use the above command in a script! Wiser usage is:

```
(cd /FolderToDeleteWithin && eval $(ls -td *.tar | awk 'NR>7 { print "rm \"" $0 "\""}'))
```

In the case of using `ls -t` command will not do any harm on such silly examples as: `touch 'foo " bar'` and `touch 'hello * world'`. Not that we ever create files with such names in real life!

Sidenote. If we wanted to pass a variable to the sh this way, we would simply modify the print (simple form, no spaces tolerated):

```
print "VarName="$1
```

to set the variable `VarName` to the value of `$1`. Multiple variables can be created in one go. This `VarName` becomes a normal sh variable and can be normally used in a script or shell afterwards. So, to create variables with awk and give them back to the shell:

```
eval $(ls -td *.tar | awk 'NR>7 { print "VarName=\""$1"\""  }'); echo "$VarName"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
leaveCount=5
fileCount=$(ls -1 *.log | wc -l)
tailCount=$((fileCount - leaveCount))

# avoid negative tail argument
[[ $tailCount < 0 ]] && tailCount=0

ls -t *.log | tail -$tailCount | xargs rm -f
```

Comment: `xargs` without `-0` or at bare minimum `-d $'\n'` is unreliable; observe how this behaves with a file with spaces or quote characters in its name.

Answer (score 0):

I made this into a bash shell script. Usage: `keep NUM DIR` where NUM is the number of files to keep and DIR is the directory to scrub.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Keep last N files by date.
# Usage: keep NUMBER DIRECTORY
echo ""
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 NUMFILES DIR"
    echo "Keep last N newest files."
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -e $2 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: directory '$1' does not exist"
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -d $2 ]; then
    echo "ERROR: '$1' is not a directory"
    exit 1
fi
pushd $2 > /dev/null
ls -tp | grep -v '/' | tail -n +"$1" | xargs -I {} rm -- {}
popd > /dev/null
echo "Done. Kept $1 most recent files in $2."
ls $2|wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified version of the answer of @Fabien if you want to specify a path. Useful if you're running the script elsewhere.

`ls -tr /path/foo/ | head -n -5 | xargs -I% --no-run-if-empty rm /path/foo/%`

Answer (score 0):

Since [SC2010 – ShellCheck Wiki](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2010) warns parsing `ls` ouput is *bad*, I propose a simple one-liner with `stat` without cryptic `awk`/`sed` scripting:

```
stat -c '%y %n' /path/* | sort -r | tail -n +2 | cut -d' ' -f4 | xargs -r rm -v --
```

`tail`'s `+2` parameter controls how many of the newest files are left behind i.e. not deleted. For an input value of `N` you are left with `N-1` of the newest files.

Comment: Note that `stat` isn't portable, and your specific command fails on macOS, for instance. When it does work, it is subject to the same - largely hypothetical - limitation as parsing `ls` output: lack of support for filenames with embedded newlines. That said, if there are cases where that is truly a concern, you could do something like `stat --printf='%y %n\0'`, but that too wouldn't be portable. Also note that  `-f4` should be `-f4-` in order to support filenames with spaces.