# How to get the most recent file using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I have a list of zip files with date and time appended like `yyyymmdd_hhmmss_Demos.zip`. Now how to get the most recently added zip file in the source dir. I need to copy this file in the target using `copy` command.

I found some info about `forfiles`, but do not have an idea on how to get it done for seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I write a Windows batch script to copy the newest file from a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97371/how-do-i-write-a-windows-batch-script-to-copy-the-newest-file-from-a-directory) It's not clear whether you want the most recently modified file, the file most recently added to the directory, or the file with the highest yyyymmdd_hhmmss.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use

```
pushd D:\a
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a
copy "%newest%" D:\b
popd
```

Comment: for the sake of simplicity i just put a set of text files in a folder a and made target as folder b and hence wrote this command 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir D:\a /b /od') do set newest=%%a
copy "%newest%" D:\b 
But this does not work for me.. what is wrong

Comment: @azzaxp Try my updated answer. It seems the directory was the problem for some reason, I'm not sure why.

Comment: `dir /b /od` will list also subdirs, if any. I think you should exclude them using `/a-d` switch (unless of course OP wants to copy subdirs also)

Comment: @wmz No, it doesn't. The `/s` switch lists subfolders, try it and see :)

Comment: sorry wrong wording. I meant that it will include names of any subdirs, not their contents (for this as you correctly stated you would need /s). So it will find newest **file** or **directory**

Comment: @azzaxp sorry to bring this back up years later haha. Im trying this solution though unlike op i need to copy the latest folder not sure if that makes a difference, but when i run this i just get a list of it setting the last created directory being set to newest, for some reason the copy doesn't seem to work though, is there a switch or something i should be using to make it work with folders?

Answer (score 2):

```
set Path="D:\hello\abc\old"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /A:-D /B /O:-D /S %Path%') do set NEW=%%a&& goto:n 
:n
echo %NEW%
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pushd \\ryap\CONTROL_DATOS
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir \\ryap\CONTROL_DATOS /b /od') do set newest=%%a
Xcopy/Y "\\ryap\CONTROL_DATOS\%newest%" "D:\TXT_SOURCES\"
popd
```

Comment: Pasting some code without explaining what it does is not so useful. Can you add a description?

Answer (score 0):

Below snippet will extract the date and customize as per your needs

```
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%i in ("%date%") do (
     set dow=%%i
     set month=%%j
     set day=%%k
     set year=%%l
)
:: Pad digits with leading zeros e.g Sample_01-01-21.csv
    set yy=%year:~-2%
    set datestr=%day%-%month%-%yy%
```

Alternate way:

```
set datestr=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,2%
```