# Copy latest 2 files using Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

Related: [How to get the most recent file using a batch script in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539726/how-to-get-the-most-recent-file-using-a-batch-script-in-windows)

I want to copy the latest 2 files from a directory using Windows batch script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET transfer=xx
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir/b/a-d/o-d *.*') DO IF DEFINED transfer CALL SET transfer=%%transfer:~1%%&ECHO %%i
```

Just set TRANSFER to a length of #transfers to execute; obviously replace `echo %%i` with an appropriate COPY command

Answer (score 0):

My version based on [Peter Wright](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2128947/peter-wright)'s answer...

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set j=0

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ('dir /b /a-d /o-d *.*') DO (
    echo %%i
    set /A j=j+1
    if !j! geq 2 (
        goto :end
    )
)
:end
```