# Select last modified file in a Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am using a tool that generates an `.apk` file which I wish to automatically install and launch. I created an extremely simple batch script for this, however the filename of the `.apk` file changes based on the version number, so I am forced to change my `.bat` file during every version change.

How can I select the most recently modified file in a `.bat` script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the most recent file using a batch script in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539726/how-to-get-the-most-recent-file-using-a-batch-script-in-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following for loop loops through all the files in directory and sets the variable `%FILE_TO_INSTALL%` each time leaving the last value set as the correct one.

```
@ECHO OFF
for /f %%i in ('dir /b/a-d/od/t:w') do set FILE_TO_INSTALL=%%i >NUL
echo Installing %FILE_TO_INSTALL%
@ECHO ON
```

And just in case somebody ends up here though google with the exact same scenario as me, here is the rest:

```
adb install -r %FILE_TO_INSTALL%
adb shell monkey -p %NAME_OF_YOUR_APP% -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```