# Store randomized folder in a batch script?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a script that automatically backup NAPS2 (Scanner program) newest scan result to another drive, and also rename it according its timestamp...
Problem is, NAPS2 uses randomized folder name as the parentfolder of its scan result... e.g 
"C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NAPS2\recovery\4j4v.fbmv\scanresult001.jpg"

Here's the code, how do i point to that randomized folder?

```
SET ROOTDIR=C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Roaming\NAPS2\recovery\
for /f %%i in ('dir %ROOTDIR% /b /AD /od /t:w') do set LATEST_DIR=%%i >NUL
SET RANDOMDIR=%ROOTDIR%%LATEST_DIR%
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "%RANDOMDIR%\*.jpg"') do set Youngest=%%a
echo Backing up %Youngest%

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
set mydate=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%@%HH%%Min%%Sec%

copy "%Youngest%" "D:\Backup\%mydate%.jpg"
```

Output

```
C:\>for /F "delims=" %a in ('dir /b /od "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Roaming\NAPS2
\recovery\jfwkui0s.pmd \*.jpg"') do set Youngest=%a
File Not Found

C:\>echo Backing up
Backing up

C:\>for /F "delims=" %a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime | find "."') do set dt=%a


 :\>set dt=20160818125756.950000+420

C:\>set YYYY=2016

C:\>set MM=08

C:\>set DD=18

C:\>set HH=12

C:\>set Min=57

C:\>set Sec=56

C:\>set mydate=20160818@125756

C:\>copy "" "D:\Backup\20160818@125756.jpg"
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

I think it's probably because the randomized folder has "." in it.. I tried "New Folder" which has space in it and it doesnt work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this use the approach shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30311479/6550457

You'll want to do it only for directories though so instead of `a-d` use `ad`

```
    SET ROOTDIR=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NAPS2\recovery\
    for /f %%i in ('dir %ROOTDIR% /b /AD /od /t:w') do set LATEST_DIR=%%i>NUL
    echo Latest Dir = %LATEST_DIR%
```

so in your script you'd use it as:

```
    SET ROOTDIR=C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NAPS2\recovery\
    for /f %%i in ('dir %ROOTDIR% /b /AD /od /t:w') do set LATEST_DIR=%%i>NUL
    SET RANDOMDIR=%ROOTDIR%%LATEST_DIR%
    echo Backing up %RANDOMDIR%

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
    set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
    set MM=%dt:~4,2%
    set DD=%dt:~6,2%
    set HH=%dt:~8,2%
    set Min=%dt:~10,2%
    set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
    set mydate=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%@%HH%%Min%%Sec%

    copy "%RANDOMDIR%" "E:\Backup\%mydate%.png"
```

Comment: How do i call the latest_dir? Getting "file not found" with this... But it lists the random folder correctly 

for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Roaming\NAPS2\recovery\%LATEST_DIR%\*.png"') do set Youngest=%%a
copy "C:\Users\Operator\AppData\Roaming\NAPS2\recovery\%LATEST_DIR%\%Youngest%" "E:\Backup\%mydate%.png"

Comment: I've added the usage in my answer.

Comment: for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "%RANDOMDIR%\*.jpg"') do set Youngest=%%a My script also needs youngest function.. but Im getting file not found when running this. .edited the main question

Comment: @denywinarto put code into backticks `\`likethis\`` or no one can read what you write

Comment: If youngest is supposed to be the random folder name then just rename latest_dir to youngest.

Comment: youngest is the latest image scan result in jpg format inside that random folder`for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir  /b /od "%RANDOMDIR%\*.jpg"') do set Youngest=%%a
echo Backing up %Youngest%` why is this not working?

Comment: `"%RANDOMDIR%\*.jpg"` it's already there :) The error is strange, `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\NAPS2\recovery\randomfolder  .jpg File not Found` there's a space after random folder

Comment: Post your current script and the output as an edit and I'll have a look.

Comment: The problem is `%%i >NUL` should be `%%i>NUL`