# DOS: Copy one file (oldest) at a time

Tags: command, dos

There is a folder which contains many zip files. I want to copy only oldest zip file on each commmand execution. Please help? Thanks

Comment: "only oldest zip file one at a time" - How many "oldest" files do you have?!

Comment: Here oldest mean: based on all files in the folder.

Comment: I used to believe that there can only be *one* **oldest** file in a folder.

Comment: You want to succesively copy single files, in the order of their creation time?

Comment: Yes thats right. Thats what I meant copy oldest file (that can be only one). Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [How do I write a Windows batch script to copy the newest file from a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97371/how-do-i-write-a-windows-batch-script-to-copy-the-newest-file-from-a-directory) - but reversing the file order

FOR /F "delims=" %%I IN ('DIR *.* /B /O:D') DO COPY %%I NewDirectoryPath & EXIT