# What's wrong with my batch script that moves the newest file from one folder to another?

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I'm trying to put together a Windows batch script that moves the most recent file to a different directory.  Here's my batch script [mostly stolen from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97371/how-do-i-write-a-windows-batch-script-to-copy-the-newest-file-from-a-directory):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.*') DO move %%G C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\ & exit /b
```

When I run this it moves every file in the folder.  Interestingly, when I replace the MOVE command with a COPY command, the script copies only one file:

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /b *.*') DO copy %%G C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\ & exit /b
REM ---------------------------------------^^^^
```

Why is the move script moving every file while the copy script is only copying one file?  Is it possibly because my script file is also in that folder and because of my edits, it is the most recent file?

Edit: Here are the contents of my source folder:

- myBatchFile.bat
- newest.txt
- oldest.txt
- second.txt

Of the *.txt files, newest.txt has the most recent modified date.  Of all of the files regardless of extension, myBatchFile.bat has the most recent modified date given that I keep making edits to it to try to get it to work.

Edit #2:  Here's a screenshot of my command window after running the first command above.  This shows that all of the files in my source folder are copied when I only expect the newest file to be copied.

[image]

Comment: I'd use `dir /b /o:-d /a:-d *.*`, so you sort items by date (newest first) and exclude directories; instead of `%%G` I recommend using `"%%~fG` to provide the full path; for the sake of readability I'd put parenthesis `()` around the code after `do` (although I think that does not make any difference in operation)...

Comment: @aschipfl, it'd take you as much effort to write it in an answer, probably adding an explanation that "your posted code repeats the `do` action for every file, so you should exit the loop after moving the file by using `goto`, for example`.

Comment: @wOxxOm, The repeated "DO" is not causing the problem with the my second command, the one that uses COPY instead of MOVE.  My second command copies only one file even though the folder contains several files.

Comment: @user2023861, sorry, I was blind. Indeed, it's strange since both your examples should exit after the first file is processed.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I provided an answer as requested...

Comment: The lines shown in the screenshot are *very* strange; behind the second `move` commad there is just an `&` but the `exit /b` is missing; I guess the `for` command becomes confused when the batch file itself is moved (note that `cmd` does *not* read the batch file into memory prior to execution); so the best solution would be to exclude the batch file -- if this is a possible option for you...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `dir /b /o:-d /a:-d *.*`, so the items are sorted by date (newest first) and directories are excluded. Otherwise the sort order is not clear, and directories like `.` (current) or `..` (parent) might be returned unintentionally.

Instead of `%%G` I recommend using `"%%~fG"` to provide the full path, surrounded by doublequotes. Also the destination path should be enclosed in `""` to avoid troubles with whitespaces.

The `FOR /F` should be changed to `"delims="` in case the file name starts with a space (which I think is valid in Windows). `"tokens=*"` removed them.

Furthermore, I'd put parenthesis `()` around the code after `do` (so it is guaranteed and obvious that both commands `move` and `exit /b` are part of the loop context).

So all in all this leads to the following code:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /o:-d /a:-d *.*') DO (move "%%~fG" "C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\" & exit /b)
```

Since the newest file is enumerated first and the `for` body contains `exit /b` (exit batch file), only that file is moved.
If you need to execute some other code after this line, replace `exit /b` by `goto :SKIP` (or any other valid label), and state the label (`:SKIP`) immediately after the `FOR` command block.

---

If the batch script containing the code herein is located in its working directory, moving it (in case it is the newest file) most likely results in unexpected behaviour. You can exclude the batch script itself by filtering it out using `find` like this:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /o:-d /a:-d *.* ^| find /v /i "%~nx0"') DO (move "%%~fG" "C:\Users\jrobinson\Desktop\" & exit /b)
```

`%~nx0` therein expands to the file name and extension of this script (see `call /?`).

Comment: That didn't work.  It still moves all of the files in my source folder rather than just the newest file.  I found that if I change the wildcard in the `dir` command from `*.*` to `*.txt`, it will move only the newest *.txt file.  This is true even if I have multiple *.txt files in my source folder.

Comment: That's weird! I'll try to figure it out... so your batch is the newest file in the source directory? what if you place another file there which is newer -- does it work then?

Comment: it does.  I put in a newer text file and the script only copied that file.  It looks like it works as long as the script file is not the newest file being moved.  Probably what I'll have to do is keep the script in a separate folder.  Thanks.

Comment: `cmd` does not buffer a batch file in memory for execution, I think this disrupts the `for` loop; so you could 1. place the batch file somewhere else, or 2. exclude it from being processed programmatically; if you want to go for option 2., I can regard it in my answer, just let me know

Comment: wow.  For your option #2, is that what the other user posted below concerning `%~nx0`?  I'm guessing that that's the variable name for the file?

Comment: Yes, the `%~nx0` portion expands to the scripts file name and ext.; see my edit -- I implemented a filter option in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I believe what you say. Because when I type the same command, is a file that I see first followed by the `PAUSE` command (or `exit`)

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %G IN ('dir /b *.*') DO @echo  %G & pause
```

So it always goes first action on the first file and the script will stop.

See this 5 secs gifv: http://i.imgur.com/kyHdN1Y.gifv with the following code:

```
@echo off

if exist ..\destination-test-folder\nul rd /s /q ..\destination-test-folder
if not exist ..\destination-test-folder\nul md ..\destination-test-folder

copy nul newest.txt>nul
copy nul oldest.txt>nul
copy nul second.txt>nul
dir /b .
pause>nul

echo: &echo For loop command: &echo:
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b "*.*"') do if "%%g" neq "%~nx0" move %%g ..\destination-test-folder>nul & echo pause is stated after each iteration & echo         1 file(s) moved. &pause>nul

echo: &echo list destination:
dir /b "..\destination-test-folder" &echo: &echo list source: &echo: 
dir /b .
```

Comment: I don't know how to prove to you that I'm not making this up.  I don't know why someone would make this up.  The only difference between the command I have that effects only one file and the command I have the effects every file is that the former is a COPY and the latter is a MOVE.

Comment: I posted a screenshot in my question that shows all of the files being moved

Comment: I tried your one line loop and it echoed only the name of the newest file.  But I replaced the echo command with a MOVE command, and it moved every file in my source folder.  However, I pulled the loop out of your code block and inserted a MOVE command, `for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('dir /b "*.*"') do if "%%g" neq "%~nx0" move %%g ..\ & exit /b` and this worked.  I think that condition fixed it, but I don't know what `%~nx0` means.  Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say thanks person: aschipfl 
You are my hero.

here is the command I used to move all read only files to a sub folder "temp"

```
md temp
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /b /o:-d /a:R *.*') DO (move "%%~fG" "temp" )
```