# Batch file to copy newest excel file in new folder

Tags: excel, batch-file

I want to copy the newest excel spreadsheet (.xlsm) into a new folder. However the problem is my original data dump folder with thousands of excel and word documents is too big to navigate.

I found a link "[How do I write a Windows batch script to copy the newest file from a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97371/how-do-i-write-a-windows-batch-script-to-copy-the-newest-file-from-a-directory)" but it does not address the  component of copying excel files at all.

Can anybody fill up the gap by showing the way ahead?

Thanks for your help!

Newlearner

Comment: See `for /?` and `dir /?`.

Comment: Can you not simply amend that script to use `*.xlsm`, instead of `*.*`?