# Windows batch file - Upload only latest file to FTP

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

I want to do an automatic file transfer from Windows server to my FTP.

Problem is that file is generated with timestamp in its name (the name is not fixed). So I need to upload always only the last version (newest) of file (based on the actual file timestamp, not timestamp in the name). Is there any way how to do that?

Running under Windows Server 2003. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To select the newest file in a Windows batch file, see
[How do I write a Windows batch script to copy the newest file from a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97371/850848)

Based on that you can create an upload batch file like:

```
@echo off

FOR /F %%I IN ('DIR C:\source\path\*.* /B /O:D') DO SET NEWEST_FILE=%%I

echo Uploading %NEWEST_FILE%

(
    echo open ftp.example.com
    echo username
    echo password
    echo put C:\source\path\%NEWEST_FILE% /target/path/%NEWEST_FILE%
    echo bye
) > ftp.txt

ftp.exe -s:ftp.txt
```

---

For an easier and more reliable approach, use some more powerful 3rd party FTP client.

For example with [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/), you can use the [`-latest` switch](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#latest) of its [`put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put).

An example batch file (`.bat`):

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "put -latest C:\source\path\* /target/path/" ^
    "exit"
```

You can even have [WinSCP generate the script/batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) (you just need to add the `-latest` switch manually).

See [WinSCP article on Uploading the most recent file](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_most_recent_file).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*