# Put only latest file into SFTP server in batch file

Tags: batch-file, sftp

I have an ETL (SSIS) job which creates a file in a folder named as `TEST_20170505.csv` before it sends the file to an SFTP server.

There would be multiple file in the folder such as, `TEST_20170504.csv`, `TEST_20170503.csv`. Currently I am using following `sftp` script file (`File.txt`) in a batch file.

```
lcd E:\localpath\
cd \sftpserverpath\
ascii
put *.csv
bye
```

This is my `.bat` file.

```
sftp -oIdentityFile=E:\sftp\filepath\ssh.ppk -B E:\sftp\filepath\File.txt username@ipaddress
```

But this will upload all the files in the local path to SFTP server instead of taking the latest/last modified/current date file.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSSH `sftp` cannot do this on its own. But you can use some fancy batch file construct to select the latest file and then generate an ad-hoc `sftp` upload script.

Some references:

- [How do I write a Windows batch script to copy the newest file from a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/97371/850848)
- [Windows batch file - Upload only latest file to FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39971561/850848)

---

Or use some more advanced Windows command-line SFTP client.

For example with [WinSCP scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation), it's as easy as using [`-latest` switch in the `put` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_put#latest):

```
open sftp://username@example.com/ -privatekey=ssh.ppk
lcd E:\localpath\
cd \sftpserverpath\
ascii
put -transfer=ascii -latest *.csv
exit
```

Run the script (`upload.txt`) like:

```
winscp.com /script=upload.txt /ini=nul /log=upload.log
```

You can even have [WinSCP generate the script/batch file for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) (you just need to add the `-latest` switch manually).

References:

- [Uploading the most recent file with WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_upload_most_recent_file)
- [Converting OpenSSH SFTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_psftp_script_to_winscp)

---

*Note that WinSCP uses .ppk format of private key files. While OpenSSH `sftp` uses PEM format. Even though your key file is named .ppk, it cannot be real .ppk file, otherwise the `sftp` would reject it. You have probably converted original .ppk file to PEM, but incorrectly kept an original extension. You have to use the original .ppk file with WinSCP (if you do not have it, you can convert the PEM back to .ppk using PuTTYgen).*

---

*Also note that WinSCP actually supports the text/ascii mode (`-transfer=ascii`), while `sftp` does not (there's no `ascii` command).*

---

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Answer (score -1):

The solution is instead of "put *.csv" in your script file, you specify the actual filename you want to upload