# cmd exclude subfolders when doing @move "%f"

Tags: cmd, move

I am using this code to move pdf files from the folder "PDF" to "PDF\old"

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "for /r c:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PDF\ %f in (*.pdf) do @move "%f" c:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PDF\old"
```

however, when there's a subfolder ("PDF\sub") with more PDFs, they will get moved to the folder "PDF\old" too - can the command be restricted to exclude any subfolders?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Check out [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) and its options `/MOV` and `/XD`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing it too complex.

Moving all pdf files to another folder - the easiest way:

```
move "c:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PDF\*.pdf" "c:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\PDF\old"
```

Comment: of course, why was I doing it the difficult way? Thanks :-)

Comment: @teaspoon you are welcome. Well the point of loops is to do something in or with subfolders and/or files within them. For simple operations like yours it is overkill. For such tasks it is best to use command line commands created for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you mean when you say exclude subfolders?

```
for /f "delims=*" %F in ('dir /b "C:\users\admin\desktop\pdf\*.pdf"') do @move "%F" "c:\users\admin\desktop\pdf\old"
```

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8905993/4725495) answer to a related question might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thanks, this works too. Funny enough, though, it is Case-sensitive. Also, due to some bug, when I was in the destination folder in Total Commander (the active window), the files wouldn't copy...