# MS Dos Batch delete old files in directory

Tags: batch-file, dos, delete-file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

I'm trying to make a DoS Batch file to go through a directory with about 500,000 files in it, and i would like it to delete all the files older then 1 year

Here's my code so far

```
@echo off
title File Exclusion Act
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b "C:\Users\Travis\Desktop\LotsOfFiles"`) do echo %%f
pause
```

So far it loops and prints out all the files in the specified directory.

Any tips/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please see this thread
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days

Comment: @Art: I reviewed that thread, and all threads mentioned in it at all levels, and just found one (not very efficient) DOS Batch based solution that does not use FORFILES...

Answer (score 3):

The Batch file below must be called with the number of days for old files to remove from today. For example, use 365 to remove 1 year old files.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :DateToJDN %date% oldDate= -%1
for /F "skip=5 tokens=1-4*" %%a in ('dir /A:-D /O:D') do (
   call :DateToJDN %%a fileDate=
   if !fileDate! lss %oldDate% (
      del "%%e"
   ) else (
      goto :EOF
   )
)
goto :EOF

:DateToJDN Date JDN= [+-days]
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%x in ("%1") do set /A mm=10%%x %% 100, dd=10%%y %% 100, yy=%%z
if %mm% lss 3 set /A mm+=12, yy-=1
set /A a=yy/100, b=a/4, c=2-a+b, e=36525*(yy+4716)/100, f=306*(mm+1)/10, %2=C+DD+E+F-1524%3
exit /B
```

If your %date% format is not MM/DD/YYYY, reorder mm, dd and yy variables in the first line of :DateToJDN subroutine.

Comment: Unable to run this. Get a `Missing operand. The syntax of the command is incorrect.` at `if !fileDate! lss %oldDate%`