# Batch script to archive logs by zipping

Tags: batch-file, zip, archive

I have a requirement for a batch script. I have log file under below directory (actually multiple directories with different names under `E:\TIBCO\`).

`E:\TIBCO\*\6.0.0\LogFiles` with `Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.*.*`

I need to perform below steps with the batch script

1. move (copy and delete) all the files that are with `Spotfire.Dxp.*.*.*` (ex Spotfire.Dxp.*.1.*)  from the above paths to `E:\TIBCO\logsArchival\rotatedDir`
2. zip all the files that are older than 60 from `E:\TIBCO\logsArchival\rotatedDir` to `E:\TIBCO\logsArchival\ArchiveDir`
3. delete the zip files that are older than 120 days from `E:\TIBCO\logsArchival\ArchiveDir`

All the above steps need to be written to the logs.

Comment: What is your problem with this batch script? What have you tried and where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at these links, where your requirement has been addressed before:
[MS Dos Batch delete old files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746778/ms-dos-batch-delete-old-files-in-directory/9747065#9747065) and [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

You can easily customize those scripts to accomplish the remaining compression of the files. Please note, that in DOS the compress command is `COMPACT`. Use `COMPACT /H` for usage information.