# Delete all files after date

Tags: date, batch-file, time, cmd, delete-file

I have created a batch file that deletes all .txt files in a folder and its sub directories.  But now I need it to delete all files before a certain date because I want it to keep the .txt files created in the last 60 days.  I need to delete 1.6 million files and the code below is most efficient for that.

Here is my code:

```
cd /BASE_PATH
del /s *.txt
```

How can I edit the code above to delete files before 8/19/15?

I need to keep similar code because other methods of deleting .txt files are too slow for my file amounts.

Comment: You can use the FORFILES command to accomplish that. http://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [batch file to delete files older than a specified date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324267/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-a-specified-date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go,

```
forfiles -p "C:\folder1\folder2" -s -m *.* -d <Number of days> -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

For Windows7 you may use

```
forfiles -p "C:\folder1\folder2" -s -m *.* /D -<Number of days> /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: And this will delete files BEFORE the "number of days"? Correct?

Comment: Yes, It deletes files before N days - you can also try out in test enviroment before the actual deletion. Kind Regards

Comment: Just two more tips: Use `/d +0` to delete everything added today. Add `/q` to your `del` or `rmdir` commands to avoid being prompted for each file or folder.