# Forfiles Batch Script (Escaping @ character)

Tags: batch-file, forfiles

I'm working on a batch script that will let me delete files older then a set period using [forfiles](http://www.ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html). For now, I'm aiming at printing the files that will be deleted.

The forfiles invocation I'm using works flawlessly from a cmd.exe shell, but as soon as I embed it into a batch script, it barfs. I suspect that this is due to the @ character not being escaped properly, but I'm not certain.

The command I'm running is:

```
forfiles /S /P "r:\" /m *.bak /d -10 /c "cmd /c echo @PATH"
```

And it results in the following error:

```
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@PATH'
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.
```

I've googled all over the place and tried a few different schemes for escaping the @PATH component. Everything from **@@PATH**, to **\"@PATH\"** with no results.

Any help would be appreciated!

I should also note that I'm basing a lot of my knowledge of forfiles from [here.](http://winhlp.com/node/180)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I had the same problem until I removed the quotation marks around the directory path , like this:

```
forfiles /S /P r:\ /m *.bak /d -10 /c "cmd /c echo @PATH"
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Removing the quotes worked!

Thanks a lot!

It seems incredibly strange to me that putting quotes around a file path (a standard procedure) would break a separate argument to the command in such a non-obvious way.

Comment: Yes, its rather bizarre, but I've had the same problem just now.  Nice solution. :)

Comment: Thanks but this is stupid.  Why, in 2012, did I have to convert my path to a DOS `f:\MySQLB~1\` format??   LOL.  But at least it works now!

Comment: @#)$(^& Makes want to stab a baby seal... Thanks. For the life of me, I never would have guessed that - I have one script WITH the /P in quotes... second won't run with it in quotes.

Comment: Thanks @DaveParsons, that must win an obscure bug award. My baby seal is safe, for now...

Comment: The baby seal is still alive! The solution from @lolquotes is a bit better imo.

Comment: This is still coming in useful 9 years later, long after the person that wrote the answer deleted their account lol...

Answer (score 27):

Try trimming the trailing `\` from your `/P` path. Then you should be able to use quotes to encapsulate a path that includes a space.

Comment: this also works and is probably a better approach as it will let you handle names with spaces

Comment: After over an hour of trying things, this was the answer for me. Thankyou!

Comment: Great. Just great.

Comment: Trimming off the `\ `in `r:\ `does no longer point to the root of drive `r:`!

Answer (score 6):

This an old question but I've got a different answer... in case anyone needs it.

When using 'forfiles', the path (written after /p) CAN be between quotation marks. However, it must not end with a slash.

If you want to run 'forfiles' for the root directory of a drive:
`forfiles /p "C:" /c "cmd /c echo @file"`

If you want to process files in a different directory...
`forfiles /p "C:\Program Files" /c "cmd /c echo @file"`

In other words, the safest approach is:

- Always use quotation marks (because folders with spaces, like 'Program Files', will still work)
- Always omit the last trailing slash

`forfiles /p "C:\Path\Without\Trailing\Slash"`

Comment: Just noticed that Abdul Rahman and lolquotes have pretty much summarized my answer... in December 2011. Oh well!

Comment: This answer does not work. Specifying a drive letter and colon (e.g. "D:") for the path will force FORFILES to look on the current directory for that drive (each drive maintains it's own 'current directory').

Comment: Always omit the last trailing slash - That was the clincher for me

Answer (score 2):

Best practice would be to use double-quote marks around the path (/P) parameter to handle paths with spaces.

The issue occurs when the substitution variable contains a trailing backslash. The backslash 'escapes' the quote, causing FORFILES to mis-interpret the rest of the command line.

By convention, the path to a directory does not need the trailing backslash, the one exception to this being the root directory. Specifying only the drive letter and a colon `C:` does NOT refer to the root - rather it refers to the 'current directory' for that drive. To refer to the root, one must use the trailing backslash `C:\`.

My solution is as follows:

When using FORFILES, append a `.` prior to the closing " of the `/P` parameter e.g.

```
FORFILES /P "%somePath%." /C "CMD /C ECHO @path"
```

After substitution, this leads to paths of the form `C:\.`,`C:\TEMP.` or `C:\TEMP\.`. All of these are treated correctly by FORFILES and also DIR.

I have not tested all the possible FORFILES substitution variables but `@path` appears to be unaffected by the addition of the `.`

Answer (score 0):

Put `forfiles.exe` to get it to work right, otherwise it will not pass the `@variables` when you use a batch file.  Forfiles will work if you are at the command prompt, but when you run it in a batch file the variables don't work right unless you put:  `forfiles.exe`.

Here is an example that deletes some txt files older than 30 days
`forfiles.exe /P c:\directory\ /M *.txt /C "cmd /c del @path" /d -30`

Answer (score 0):

I found there are two versions of FORFILES, one is 1998 version (thanks to Emmanuel Boersma), and the other one is 2005 version (modified date time show it).

```
FORFILES v 1.1 - by Emmanuel Boersma - 4/98

Syntax : FORFILES [-pPath] [-mSearch Mask] [-ccommand] [-dDDMMYY] [-s]

 -pPath             Path where to start searching
 -mSearch Mask      Search files according to <Search Mask>
 -cCommand          Command to execute on each file(s)
 -d[+|-][DDMMYY|DD] Select files with date >= or <=DDMMYY (UTC)
                    or files having date >= or <= (current date - DD days)
 -s                 Recurse directories
 -v                 Verbose mode

The following variables can be used in Command :
 @FILE, @PATH, @RELPATH, @ISDIR, @FSIZE, @FDATE, @FTIME

Default : <Directory : .> <Search Mask : *.*>  <Command : "CMD /C Echo @FILE">
Examples :
FORFILES -pc:\ -s -m*.BAT -c"CMD /C Echo @FILE is a batch file"
FORFILES -pc:\ -s -m*.* -c"CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE echo @FILE is a directory"
FORFILES -pc:\ -s -m*.* -d-100 -c"CMD /C Echo @FILE : date >= 100 days"
FORFILES -pc:\ -s -m*.* -d-010193 -c"CMD /C Echo @FILE is quite old!"
```

Each version have their unique syntax.

```
FORFILES [/P pathname] [/M searchmask] [/S]
         [/C command] [/D [+ | -] {MM/dd/yyyy | dd}]

Description:
    Selects a file (or set of files) and executes a
    command on that file. This is helpful for batch jobs.

Parameter List:
    /P    pathname      Indicates the path to start searching.
                        The default folder is the current working
                        directory (.).

    /M    searchmask    Searches files according to a searchmask.
                        The default searchmask is '*' .

    /S                  Instructs forfiles to recurse into
                        subdirectories. Like "DIR /S".

    /C    command       Indicates the command to execute for each file.
                        Command strings should be wrapped in double
                        quotes.

                        The default command is "cmd /c echo @file".

                        The following variables can be used in the
                        command string:
                        @file    - returns the name of the file.
                        @fname   - returns the file name without
                                   extension.
                        @ext     - returns only the extension of the
                                   file.
                        @path    - returns the full path of the file.
                        @relpath - returns the relative path of the
                                   file.
                        @isdir   - returns "TRUE" if a file type is
                                   a directory, and "FALSE" for files.
                        @fsize   - returns the size of the file in
                                   bytes.
                        @fdate   - returns the last modified date of the
                                   file.
                        @ftime   - returns the last modified time of the
                                   file.

                        To include special characters in the command
                        line, use the hexadecimal code for the character
                        in 0xHH format (ex. 0x09 for tab). Internal
                        CMD.exe commands should be preceded with
                        "cmd /c".

    /D    date          Selects files with a last modified date greater
                        than or equal to (+), or less than or equal to
                        (-), the specified date using the
                        "MM/dd/yyyy" format; or selects files with a
                        last modified date greater than or equal to (+)
                        the current date plus "dd" days, or less than or
                        equal to (-) the current date minus "dd" days. A
                        valid "dd" number of days can be any number in
                        the range of 0 - 32768.
                        "+" is taken as default sign if not specified.

    /?                  Displays this help message.

Examples:
    FORFILES /?
    FORFILES
    FORFILES /P C:\WINDOWS /S /M DNS*.*
    FORFILES /S /M *.txt /C "cmd /c type @file | more"
    FORFILES /P C:\ /S /M *.bat
    FORFILES /D -30 /M *.exe
             /C "cmd /c echo @path 0x09 was changed 30 days ago"
    FORFILES /D 01/01/2001
             /C "cmd /c echo @fname is new since Jan 1st 2001"
    FORFILES /D +3/19/2012 /C "cmd /c echo @fname is new today"
    FORFILES /M *.exe /D +1
    FORFILES /S /M *.doc /C "cmd /c echo @fsize"
    FORFILES /M *.txt /C "cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE notepad.exe @file"
```

Have a nice time making "Batch File" more sophisticated. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
dir *.* > C:\path\dummy%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%.DAT

dir *.* > C:\path\dummy%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%.csv

forfiles -p C:\path\ -m *.DAT /d -50 /c "cmd /c del /Q @path"
forfiles -p C:\path\ -m *.csv /d -50 /c "cmd /c del /Q @path"
```

1. Replace the .dat and .csv files what u want to delete.
2. -50 delete older then 50 days
3. This is the windows batch file

Answer (score 0):

**DID NOT WORK**

`FORFILES /P %deletepath% /M *.%extension% /D -%days% /C "cmd /c del @PATH"`

**DID WORK**

`FORFILES /P %deletepath% /M *.%extension% /D -%days% /C "cmd /c del @path"`

@path in lower case works.

After searching everywhere I came across the answer in my own testing. Using the latest version on server 2012 R2 I tried changing the @PATH to lower case. This fixed it for me.

Good luck!