# Getting forfiles help page where it shouldn't

Tags: batch-file, file-io, forfiles

I'm using the following command to delete files older than X days (`%numb%` is the amount of days):

```
forfiles -p "%temp%" -s -m *.* -d %numb% -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Still, when I execute it it just prompts me with all features of forfiles and how it should be used.

Comment: If you don't wont to use any 3rd party software, look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days/1322886#1322886

Comment: Note that contrary to what MS docs say, `/m *.*` in `forfiles` does not match all files. It will only match files whose names have an extension. If you want to match *all* files, you need `/m *`. Or just omit `/m` entirely, since `/m *` is the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to change your **"DEL @path"** to **"echo @path"** until you get the kinks worked out...

On my XPsp3 machine, I noticed that a hyphen before the number of days (%numb%) was important.
So, this:

```
forfiles -p "%temp%" -s -m *.* -d 30 -c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

yeilded this:
ERROR: No files found with the specified search criteria.

but this:

```
forfiles -p "%temp%" -s -m *.* -d -30 -c "cmd /c echo @path"
```

gave me a directory listing

Comment: thanks, is giving a lot of goodness... i think the before command actually said to look 30 days next... haha.

Comment: [RobW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110275/robw) .. your answer helped a lot.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One guess, since you haven't given much information, is if you're not on 2003/Vista, then you should not have a space after each parameter:

```
forfiles -p"%temp%" -s -m*.* -d%numb% -c"cmd /c del @path"
```

It's also possible your substitution parameters are not working as expected. I find it helpful often to prefix the command with "echo" to see what's actually being processed:

```
echo forfiles -p "%temp%" -s -m *.* -d %numb% -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Answer (score 0):

Natively, you can use vbscript. this example, num days is 30

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = "c:\test"
numdays=30
today=Now
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
Go (objFolder)
Sub Go(objDIR)
  If objDIR <> "\System Volume Information" Then
    For Each eFolder in objDIR.SubFolders
        Go eFolder
    Next
    For Each strFile In objDIR.Files
        If DateDiff("d",strFile.DateLastModified,today) >= numdays Then
           WScript.Echo "file found that is 1 month old or more: " & strFile
           'objFSO.DeleteFile(strFile) 'uncomment to use
        End If 
    Next 
  End If  
End Sub
```