# Script which displays a message if the subfolders aren't updated

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I need a script which displays a message if the subfolders aren't updated within 10 minutes.

Something like:

```
   for /f %%i in ('dir /b/ad/od') do set LAST=%%i
       echo %LAST% 

   if %LAST% is about ten minutes without updating then
   echo WARNING!!! The  %LAST% folder needs updating!
```

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928552/find-out-if-file-is-older-than-4-hours-in-batch-file Just replace 4*60 by 10 and put it into a loop for all files/folders.

Comment: that post seems overly complicated. `for /D %a in (*) do echo %~ta` gives timestamps of all folders. (which you can then reformat as useful yyyymmddhhmm number and compare with a similarly formatted `%DATE% %TIME%`)