# Compare current date with file modified date in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a requirement to create a batch file and that should work in windows 2003 server.

1. I have source folder "c:\Source" and destination folder "c:\Destination".
2. I want to check all the file modified dates in source folder:

   - If the file modified date is less than current date then that file will move into destination folder
   - Otherwise, do nothing.

**Note:** as my server is production server so, I am unable to install Resource kit and           robocopy.exe. The only way is write the batch script.

`Robocopy` and `forfiles` are not working in Windows2003 server.

Comment: is PowerShell installed on your server? It will much simpler to do that in PowerShell

Comment: You don't have to "install" the Resource Kit, you can just copy RoboCopy.exe to the server and start using it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Update

Since you have `forfiles` on your server, this is easy.  To check for files older than 1 day old, just use `forfiles /D -1`.  For files over 2 days old, `/D -2`.

```
forfiles /D -2 /M *.log /P C:\Source /C "cmd /c move @file c:\Destination"
```

Enter `forfiles /?` in a console window for full syntax.

---

#### Original answer

Consider revising your requirement.  Instead of saying "If file modified date is less than the current date", you should say, "If file modified date does not equal current date".  That absolves you from having to do date math, and makes your task profoundly simpler.  After all, the last modified date is not going to be a date in the future, right?

After that, it's a simple matter of scraping today's date from `%date%` and comparing it with the date from each file's `%%~tX` substitution property in a `for` loop.  Type `help for` in a console window and see the last two pages for more information about this syntax.

I don't think there will be any locale date formatting issues with this.  As long as your system's `%date%` variable is in the format of `dayOfWeek Date` and `%%~tX` is formatted as `Date Time etc.` then this script should work regardless of whether you handle dates locally as `MM/DD/YYYY` or `YYYY/MM/DD` or `DD/MM/YYYY` or something else.  I hope.

```js
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

set "source=c:\Source"
set "destination=c:\Destination"

:: store today's date in %today%
for /f "tokens=2" %%I in ('echo %date%') do set "today=%%I"

for %%I in ("%source%\*") do (
    rem :: scrape MM/DD/YYYY from %%~tI
    for /f %%a in ('echo %%~tI') do (

        rem :: compare the two dates
        if "%%a" neq "%today%" (
            echo %%~nxI: %%a does not equal %today%.  Moving.
            >NUL move /y "%%~fI" "%destination%"
        ) else (
            echo %%~nxI: %%a equals %today%.  Skipping.
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Rojo, Thank you very much for your help,LSS is not working, if i want to move files older than 2 days.

Comment: That's a whole other issue.  Really, you'll save yourself a lot of hassle if you just copy `c:\windows\system32\forfiles.exe` onto your 2K3 server.  The batch language is horrible for date math.  You might be able to employ a JScript solution, [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27297874/1683264) perhaps but with `WSH.Echo(Math.floor(age / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24));` to get the age in days.

Comment: Hi Rojo, Yes, i have "Forfiles.exe" in c:\windows\System32 folder, can we do more on this?

Comment: Hi Rojo, I have tried this command and it working as expectd. "forfiles /P "d:\source" /S /M *.* /D -2 /C "cmd /C move @file "d:\dest"". Thanks a lot for your inputs.

Comment: @Kranthi Cool.  I was updating my answer as you were doing your own testing it seems.  :)