# Batch Script For File Date/Time

Tags: date, batch-file, time, dayofweek

I know there are similar questions but I have not been able to make any work. I need to check a particular file date and time against the current date and time.
So far I have

```
 Set cdate=%date%
 Set filename="c:\myfile"
 If Not Exist %filename% GOTO CREATEFILE
 For %%f In(%filename%) DoSet filedatetime=%%~tf
 If %filedatetime:~0,-9%" == "%cdate% GOTO SHOFILE
```

My problem is that the cdate returned has the day of the week included in the date but the file date does not. Example  cdate= Thur 1/01/2015. How can I get the cdate not to have the day of the week?
Thanks

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27714991/1683264) for a way to scrape MM/DD/YYYY from both `%date%` and `%%~tX`.  You can also `set "cdate=%date:* =%"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 For %%f In (%filename%) Do Set "filedatetime=%%~tf"
 If "%filedatetime:~0,-9%"=="%cdate:~4%" GOTO SHOFILE
```

Note the **required** space after `in` and `do`

The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`.

`if /i "%var%"=="value"` performs a comparison on variables/values containing separators (eg spaces) The '/i' make the comparison case-insensitive if required.

Answer (score 1):

Your `cdate` can be set like this:

```
SET cdate=%date:~4%
```

This has the following output:

```
echo %cdate%
01/01/2015
```