# how to delete all files last modified more than 5 minutes ago?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

This is the command i am running which deletes all files in directory

```
set folder="C:\dashboard\DATA"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

How do i only delete the files that were last modified more than 5 minutes ago

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell it would be:

```
Get-ChildItem | Where-Object LastWriteTime -lt ([DateTime]::Now).AddMinutes(-5) | Remove-Item
```

Or, using usually known aliases:

```
ls | where LastWriteTime -lt ([DateTime]::Now).AddMinutes(-5) | rm
```

To use this in **bat** or **cmd** you can invoke PowerShell explicitly:

```
powershell -NoProfile -Command "ls c:\path | where LastWriteTime -lt ([DateTime]::Now).AddMinutes(-5) | rm"
```

Comment: what about Cmd?

Comment: I expect plain cmd to be a mess. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296934/file-is-older-than-4-minutes-in-batch-file

Comment: With a batch file you can write some thing like that : `@echo off & powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "ls C:\dashboard\DATA | where LastWriteTime -lt ([DateTime]::Now).AddMinutes(-5) | rm -WhatIf" & pause`

Comment: You do not need to use or waste realestate with `-ExecutionPolicy` when using `-Command`s. An execution policy is required only when running PowerShell scripts, _(i.e. `-File`s)_.

Answer (score 0):

With a batch file you can write something like that :

---

```bat
@echo off
Powershell -C "ls C:\dashboard\DATA | where LastWriteTime -lt ([DateTime]::Now).AddMinutes(-5) | rm -WhatIf"
pause
```

If everything is OK , just remove `-WhatIf`