# Unusual error with date in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have written a batch script and i made a time-stamp variable for the folder's name.
Everything was ok until yesterday, cause someone told me that the script is not working. I found that the error is on folder's name.

I use this command:

```
@set datetimef=%date:~0,2%_%date:~4,2%
```

and the results are the following:

My Computer: `26_10`.

in not working Computer: `MON_ 1`.

Could someone explain me where is my error ?

Comment: `%date%` value depends on the machine settings.To get indepence of local settings time stamps [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/388389)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current datetime on Windows command line, in a suitable format for using in a filename?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us)

Comment: @Mofi It's not duplicated because i asked why the time stamp is not the same in all PCs and the answer was that `%date%` value depends on the machine settings. The other users asked how to get current datetime and i don't asked that, so simple. Thank you

Comment: @poprock Well, `Unusual error with date in batch script` is not really a question. Your code line does not contain any error. Searching on Stack Overflow with [\[batch-file\] date](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+date) returns more than 4000 posts and in many of them is written that date format of variable __DATE__ depends on Windows region and language settings and `wmic` offers a method to get date and time in a region independent format. For a comprehensive answer on usual date/time processing issues read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32670346/3074564).