# Batch code if date created is less than 24 hours

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, datemodified

I have already written here for this problem, we solved it, but now I have to add this "if the file was created in the last 24 hours copy it else don't". I have found several examples online but I just cant seem to be able to figure the Command syntax out. I would really apreciate some help with this ... here is the website I found:

https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/fileUtils/fileModifiedTime.bat

and here is my code:

```
ECHO OFF
set ReadFolder1="C:\Users\ugrum\Desktop\new"    
set Destination="C:\Users\ugrum\Desktop\Zacasnamapa"
set sevenZipDir="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7zG.exe"
set currentDate=%date%

IF NOT EXIST %Destination% MKDIR %Destination%

FOR /R %ReadFolder1% %%G IN (*_NOT*) DO (
    ECHO %%G 
    FOR %%f IN %%G DO SET filedatetime=%%~tf
    IF %currentDate% - %filedatetime:~0, 10% <= 24      
    XCOPY "%%G" %Destination% /C
)

%sevenZipDir% a -tzip neustrezne.zip %Destination%
RMDIR /Q /S %Destination%

PAUSE
```

I know the `if` is wrong but I have no idea how to get it right.

Comment: `FOR %%f IN (%%G) DO ` the parantheses are mandatory.

Comment: You can't calculate with Dates in CMD. You have to convert Dates to numbers before. (or use external Tools, which can)

Comment: you can find some helpful links with the [search function](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+calculate+date+time+seconds)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a batch code for your task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "ReadFolder1=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\new"
set "Destination=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Zacasnamapa"
set "SevenZipApp=%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7zG.exe"

if not exist "%Destination%" mkdir "%Destination%"

rem Get seconds since 1970-01-01 for current date and time.
rem From date string only the last 10 characters are passed to GetSeconds
rem which results in passing dd/mm/yyyy or dd.mm.yyyy in expected format
rem to this subroutine independent on date string of environment variable
rem DATE is with or without abbreviated weekday at beginning.
call :GetSeconds "%DATE:~-10% %TIME%"

rem Subtract seconds for 24 hours (24 * 3600 seconds) from seconds value.
set /A "CompareTime=Seconds-24*3600"

for /R "%ReadFolder1%" %%G in (*_NOT*) do (
    echo %%G
    set "FullFileName=%%G"
    for %%H in ("%%G") do (
        call :GetSeconds "%%~tH:0"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        if !Seconds! GTR %CompareTime% (
            echo Copy file !FullFileName!
            %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "!FullFileName!" "!Destination!\" /C /I /M /Q /R /Y >nul
        )
        endlocal
    )
)

"%SevenZipApp%" a -tzip neustrezne.zip "%Destination%"
rmdir /Q /S "%Destination%"

endlocal
goto :EOF


rem No validation is made for best performance. So make sure that date
rem and hour in string is in a format supported by the code below like
rem MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss or M/D/YYYY h:m:s for English US date/time.

:GetSeconds
rem If there is " AM" or " PM" in time string because of using 12 hour
rem time format, remove those two strings and in case of " PM" remember
rem that 12 hours must be added to the hour depending on hour value.
set "DateTime=%~1"
set "Add12Hours=0"
if not "%DateTime: AM=%" == "%DateTime%" (
    set "DateTime=%DateTime: AM=%"
) else if not "%DateTime: PM=%" == "%DateTime%" (
    set "DateTime=%DateTime: PM=%"
    set "Add12Hours=1"
)

rem Get year, month, day, hour, minute and second from first parameter.
for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=,-./: " %%A in ("%DateTime%") do (
    rem For English US date MM/DD/YYYY or M/D/YYYY
    rem set "Day=%%B" & set "Month=%%A" & set "Year=%%C"
    rem For German date DD.MM.YYYY or English UK date DD/MM/YYYY
    set "Day=%%A" & set "Month=%%B" & set "Year=%%C"
    set "Hour=%%D" & set "Minute=%%E" & set "Second=%%F"
)

rem Remove leading zeros from the date/time values or calculation could be wrong.
if "%Month:~0,1%"  == "0" if not "%Month:~1%"  == "" set "Month=%Month:~1%"
if "%Day:~0,1%"    == "0" if not "%Day:~1%"    == "" set "Day=%Day:~1%"
if "%Hour:~0,1%"   == "0" if not "%Hour:~1%"   == "" set "Hour=%Hour:~1%"
if "%Minute:~0,1%" == "0" if not "%Minute:~1%" == "" set "Minute=%Minute:~1%"
if "%Second:~0,1%" == "0" if not "%Second:~1%" == "" set "Second=%Second:~1%"

rem Add 12 hours for time range 01:00:00 PM to 11:59:59 PM,
rem but keep the hour as is for 12:00:00 PM to 12:59:59 PM.
if %Add12Hours% == 1 if %Hour% LSS 12 set /A Hour+=12

set "DateTime="
set "Add12Hours="

rem Must use two arrays as more than 31 tokens are not supported
rem by command line interpreter cmd.exe respectively command FOR.
set /A "Index1=Year-1979"
set /A "Index2=Index1-30"

if %Index1% LEQ 30 (
    rem Get number of days to year for the years 1980 to 2009.
    for /F "tokens=%Index1% delims= " %%Y in ("3652 4018 4383 4748 5113 5479 5844 6209 6574 6940 7305 7670 8035 8401 8766 9131 9496 9862 10227 10592 10957 11323 11688 12053 12418 12784 13149 13514 13879 14245") do set "Days=%%Y"
    for /F "tokens=%Index1% delims= " %%L in ("Y N N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N") do set "LeapYear=%%L"
) else (
    rem Get number of days to year for the years 2010 to 2038.
    for /F "tokens=%Index2% delims= " %%Y in ("14610 14975 15340 15706 16071 16436 16801 17167 17532 17897 18262 18628 18993 19358 19723 20089 20454 20819 21184 21550 21915 22280 22645 23011 23376 23741 24106 24472 24837") do set "Days=%%Y"
    for /F "tokens=%Index2% delims= " %%L in ("N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N N N Y N N") do set "LeapYear=%%L"
)

rem Add the days to month in year.
if "%LeapYear%" == "N" (
    for /F "tokens=%Month% delims= " %%M in ("0 31 59 90 120 151 181 212 243 273 304 334") do set /A "Days+=%%M"
) else (
    for /F "tokens=%Month% delims= " %%M in ("0 31 60 91 121 152 182 213 244 274 305 335") do set /A "Days+=%%M"
)

rem Add the complete days in month of year.
set /A "Days+=Day-1"

rem Calculate the seconds which is easy now.
set /A "Seconds=Days*86400+Hour*3600+Minute*60+Second"

rem Exit this subroutine.
goto :EOF
```

For details on the method used to compare time read my answers on

- [Find out if file is older than 4 hours in Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670346/3074564)
- [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28395552/3074564)

**Note 1:**

Format of date and time string returned by `%DATE:~-10% %TIME%` and `%%~tF:0` depends on Windows region and language settings. The code as written expects for date string `dd/mm/yyyy` or `dd.mm.yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy` and for time string `hh:mm:ss` with or without leading zeros in case of hour, minute or second is less than 10.

An abbreviated weekday at beginning of date string of environment variable **DATE** does not matter because of using only last 10 characters if the date string is with leading zero for day or month less than 10 as it is standard on Windows.

For US date format `mm/dd/yyyy` the command `rem` must be moved from one line to another line in subroutine `GetSeconds` as the comment explains.

**Note 2:**

See my answer on [set environment variables with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564) for the reason using `set "variable=value with spaces"` and reference value of `variable` enclosed in double quotes where necessary instead of using `set variable="value with spaces"` which could result in wrong code on execution.

**By the way:**

Do you have ever thought to spend a few bucks for buying a license of *WinRAR* as your task to compress all files modified within last 24 hours could be done with *WinRAR* with a single command line or by using GUI of *WinRAR*? Think about the time you and we spent to write a batch code for this very easy to solve task using *WinRAR* and compare it with the little money a single license of *WinRAR* costs.

The command line using *WinRAR* would be:

```
%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe a -ac -afzip -cfg- -ep -ibck -m5 -tn24h -y "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\neustrezne.zip" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\new\*_NOT*"
```

- **a** is the command which means **add** to an archive.
- `-ac` is a switch to clear archive attribute on each file added to archive. This is not really necessary here, but very often helpful.
- `-afzip` explicitly tells *WinRAR* to create a ZIP archive. This switch is not really necessary here as archive file name ends with `.zip` and therefore *WinRAR*  would automatically use **ZIP** instead of **RAR** compression.
- `-cfg-` disables the standard configuration for creating archives. It is always a good idea to use this switch when using *WinRAR* from within a batch file executed periodically to make archive creation independent on settings not defined on command line.
- `-ep` results in adding the files without path to the archive.
- `-ibck` tells *WinRAR* to run minimized to system tray as background application. But with the used options a dialog window is displayed if an error occurs on adding the files to the archive.
- `-m5` use best compression.
- `-tn24h` this is the nice option *WinRAR* has which 7-Zip currently does not have to add only files matching the pattern in specified directory modified within last 24 hours, i.e. newer than current date/time minus 24 hours.
- `-y` assume **yes** on all user queries.

For more details on *WinRAR* switches open in *WinRAR* from menu **Help** the **Help topics**, and open on tab **Contents** item **Command line mode** and subitem **Switches**.

Comment: To add on to Mofi's answer, if you can use PowerShell, your script could be more readable and maintainable.  Also, if your 24h requirement is flexible and is really on the day boundary, you could use robocopy and /MAXAGE to get files.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a simple solution to copying files MODIFIED within a specific date (such as "copy files where date modified is less than 24 hours"), you can use robocopy:

```
set "ORIGIN_FOLDER=C:\My Files"
set "BACKUP_FOLDER=C:\My Files (backup)"
robocopy "%ORIGIN_FOLDER%" "%BACKUP_FOLDER%" /maxage:1
```

The `/maxage` parameter allows you to set a number in days, or a date, to specify the maximum age of the file (using date modified). The above question is asking about date CREATED, but MODIFIED is often what is required. Robocopy doesn't have a parameter to use date CREATED as far as I can tell.

There are lots of parameters for specifying file properties, you can find them here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy#file-selection-options