# Dynamically naming a FOLDER for backup

Tags: batch-file, dynamic

I want to know how I can use a Batch file to copy a file from one directory to another directory, then name it with a dynamic name that uses the date of the backup as the name.
I know how to copy the file to the new DIR using xcopy (Which is sort of slow with the size of files I copy), but I can't figure out how to name the folder that they get copied to, dynamically. [if anyone has a faster solution, I'll hear it]

I've been trying to figure this out, and I know this question has been asked before, and I've tried to research it extensively,  but I'm having trouble understanding how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
@echo off

REM Find Current Year
set varYear=%date:~-4,4%

REM Find Current Month
set varMonth=%date:~-7,2%

REM Find Current Day
set varDay=%date:~-10,2%

REM Find Hour
set varHour=%time:~-11,2%

if %varHour% leq 9 (
call :trim %varHour%
goto :eof
:trim
set varHour=0%*
)
:eof

REM Find Minutes
set varMinutes=%time:~-8,2%

REM Compile Date
set DateTime=%varDay%.%varMonth%.%varYear%__%varHour%.%varMinutes%


mkdir "C:\New\Backup\Folder\%DateTime%_Backup"


xcopy /i "C:\Remote\Server" "C:\New\Backup\Folder\%DateTime%_Backup" /D/S/H/V/C/F/K/Y

exit
```

I didn't end up having to use the FOR command. I can't seem to understand how it works

Answer (score 0):

Run this batch code and you can see how to get current date assigned to environment variable `FolderDate` for usage in name of backup folder.

```
@echo off

rem Get the current local date and time in a region and language
rem independent format by using Windows Management Instrumentation.

for /F "skip=1 delims=." %%T in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS get localdatetime') do set "LocalDateTime=%%T" & goto ReformatDate

rem Convert the date and time string in format yyyymmddhhmmss like
rem 20151231150357 to a readable format with date only like 2015-12-31.

:ReformatDate
set "FolderDate=%LocalDateTime:~0,4%-%LocalDateTime:~4,2%-%LocalDateTime:~6,2%"

rem Output the date string for the backup folder and delete the 2 variables.

echo Date for backup folder is: %FolderDate%
echo.
set "LocalDateTime="
set "FolderDate="
pause
```

Read for example answer on [Find out if file is older than 4 hours in Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670346/3074564) and the answers on [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/) for details about getting and reformatting date and time string.

The usage of value of environment variable **DATE** reformatted for the folder name to format `yyyy-mm-dd` would be much faster than using `wmic`. But using **DATE** requires knowledge of date format on used machine because of depending on region and language settings.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `wmic /?`

It is also advisable to run `wmic OS get localdatetime` from within a command line window to see the output of this command line being processed by command **for** and finally resulting in the date string in format `yyyy-mm-dd` for usage in name of backup folder.

Comment: Thank you for this. I get where this is going, but the FOR command is unnecessary for what I was needing. I do appreciate the help though

Comment: @DakotaZinn The command __FOR__ in answer above is needed to get output of __wmic__ usually written to console window captured by __FOR__ and already truncated on first period assigned to the environment variable `LocalDateTime`. You don't need __FOR__ in your batch code as you are using directly region dependent environment variables __DATE__ and __TIME__ as I have suggested, too. I could not offer a solution using __DATE__ and __TIME__ as you have not written in question which format the strings of those two variables have on your computer.