# batch file: error with quote and path

Tags: batch-file

when I run the following command in cmd manually, it works

```
for /F "delims=" %f in ('dir /B C:\Users\DMS\Downloads\*^|FileByAge.exe 2') do echo %f
```

However, when I put that command in a batch file and run it, I get the following:

```
\Users\DMS\Downloads\*|FileByAge.exe was unexpected at this time.
for /F "delims=" \Users\DMS\Downloads\*^|FileByAge.exe 2') do echo f
```

Any suggestion?

I am tying to make the answer from ([Find out if file is older than 4 hours in Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928552/find-out-if-file-is-older-than-4-hours-in-batch-file)) work in my case

Comment: Use `%%f` instead of `%f` in a batch file; type `for /?` in a command prompt window for details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `%%` instead of `%` for `for` loop variables inside batch files.

```
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /B C:\Users\DMS\Downloads\*^|FileByAge.exe 2') do echo %%f
```