# Command output redirection using pipe character

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

I try to understand how output redirection to another command works.

I know that it can be used if the second command is **find** as help text to find explicitly says so. It can also be used with **findstr** although 
findstr's help text does not say anything about this.

So the question is:

How do I know what other windows command shell commands accept output from another command?

I've created a command line where I expect the output to be "18:33" but it does not work

```
C:>time /T | set /P a= && echo %a%
%a%

C:>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
C:>time /T | set /P a= && echo !a!
!a!
```

Why does this not work as expected?

*Please not that the point here is **not** reading the time to a variable. I just don't see how the pipe is useful with anything other than find or findstr.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is because windows is messed up.

There is no good reason why your commands above do not work, and microsoft is entirely to blame. Their software quite often not only fails to work, but it actually fails to work in completely nonsensical ways, and without any error message to hint at what might have gone wrong, thus wasting people's time.  If you want a decent command prompt which usually works, and in the event that it does not work it is generally due to your mistake and not its mistake, try Linux.

That having been said, there are several commands available at the windows command prompt that do process their standard input; the `sort` command is one that comes to mind.  Try `type text.txt | sort` and see what happens.

To answer your question "how do I know?", the answer is that you cannot know, because I do not think that there is a comprehensive list of all commands that process the standard input.  However, generally, if a command operates on an input file, and it requires the input file name to be specified as a parameter, and if this parameter is optional, then it is pretty safe to assume that if the parameter is omitted, the command will process its standard input.

Also, it is possible to fool a command which accepts the input file name as a non-optional parameter to use the standard input instead, by specifying `con` as the input file name.  So, for example, typing `type` alone does not work, but try `type con` and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Nearly every command that accepts input can also be used with pipes.

Also your sample with `SET /P` could work, but it needs some attention.
I don't use delayed expasion here, as it adds only more complexity.

```
time /T | ( set /P var= && set var )
```

The parenthesis are important here, else the implicit order would be

```
( time /T | set /P var= ) && set var
```

But this fails, as a pipe creates two new cmd.exe instances for both sides.
After the end of the both tasks these instances will be removed again.
Therefore it's only possible to access a variable created by a pipe inside the same (new) instance.

For many cases, pipes are useful to automate some simple questions like

```
echo Y | del *
```

Some more infos about pipes and delayed expansion at [SO:Why does delayed expansion fail when inside a piped block of code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192318/463115)

Answer (score 1):

Commands reading in data from a file often but not always support also reading in data from handle **STDIN**. The pipe character `|` redirects the output written to handle **STDOUT** of application A to handle **STDIN** of application B. For more details read the Microsoft article about [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) and SS64 article about [Redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

Which console applications support input from **STDIN** is a matter of documentation. There are just a few console applications installed with Windows supporting input from **STDIN**. But there are lots of third-party console applications supporting input from **STDIN**. Many of them don't explicitly explain in documentation that input can be read also from **STDIN** and not only from an input file specified as parameter. But support of data input from **STDIN** can be always found out very quickly with one trial.

Standard Windows console applications supporting also **STDIN** among **FIND** and **FINDSTR** are *for example* **MORE** and **SORT**.

Most standard Windows console applications and internal commands of `cmd.exe` do not process the contents of files and therefore don't support **STDIN**. For a list of Windows standard commands see [Microsoft's command-line reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands). But more details about the Windows standard command line commands can be found on the webpages linked from [SS64.com - A-Z index of the Windows CMD command line](https://ss64.com/nt/).

Redirection from **STDOUT** of an application to **STDIN** of another application is very often used with third-party console applications because many of them support input from **STDIN**. Every compiler/script interpreter writes messages to **STDOUT** and fatal error messages to **STDERR** which are redirected by many GUI text editors and IDE applications for capturing, filtering and printing those messages into a GUI window for the programmer. This redirection is done using same mechanisms as Windows command interpreter offers with the redirection operators `>` and `>>` and `|`.

In general all console applications supporting input from keyboard support also input from **STDIN** redirected from output or another application or from a file. But as always there are exceptions as for example some applications by design accept input only directly from keyboard and not from handle **STDIN** for example because of security reasons like not an application or script should confirm/enter something, but a real human user via keyboard.

---

The command **SET** is for assigning a value to an environment variable, or outputting the values of 1 or more environment variables to **STDOUT**, or evaluating an arithmetic expression, or prompting a batch user for a string reading from **STDIN**. This command is not designed for reading from a file or writing to a file.

But it is nevertheless possible to redirect output of an application to an environment variable using `set /P` and a special syntax as [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115/jeb) describes in his answer. But this method is rarely used and I think the reason is the complexity of the required expression.

However, the demo code is for assigning the current time to an environment variable. Very often there is a command parameter or another feature which avoids the need to redirect text to **STDIN** of a command or console application. This is also the case for getting an environment variable with current time as value.

There are the predefined environment variables **DATE** and **TIME**. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` and read all pages of output help. On last page some special environment variables often needed in batch file are listed with an explanation including **DATE** and **TIME**.

Try it out with

```
echo Current date is %DATE% and current time is %TIME%
```

Please note that format of date and time string returned by `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` depends on current settings in Windows Region and Language settings (country). So use `%DATE%` and `%TIME%` only if the batch file is executed always on same computer where date/time format is well known and does not change. Otherwise it is better to use `wmic.exe OS get localdatetime`. For more details about date/time usage on Windows see answer on [Find out if file is older than 4 hours in Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32670346/3074564).

The command **FOR** can be used to assign a string output by an application to 1 or more environment variables. Run in a command prompt window `for /?` for a help on this command. The method with usage of **FOR** is most often used to assign output of an application or a text read from a file to an environment variable.

Batch file example:

```
@echo off
for /F %%I in ('time /T') do set "a=%%I"
echo Time is %a%
```

Comment: Just added a comment to the original question. My point is not reading the time to a variable. I just don't see how the pipe is useful with anything other than find or findstr.

Comment: @Mofi I suppose you simply forgot the `SET /P` command, accepting user input and also input from stdin

Comment: @jeb That's right. I use never `set /P` (prompt method) to assign a string from a file or another application to an environment variable as I simply don't want to "misuse" a feature for something else that it was designed for even if it is possible. Therefore I really forgot this method. I also use never `echo Y | del *` as this works only on English Windows whereby using `del /Q *` works independent on language of Windows. But thanks for the comment correcting my answer in one important point.