# How to compare two timestamps to see if one is later for more than a specific number of minutes?

Tags: windows, batch-file, timestamp

I am trying to compare two timestamps (`timeA` against `timeB`) in the format of HH:MM without seconds, so that I can see **if `timeB` has a time which is later than 30 minutes or more than the time of `timeA`**. I can assume that `timeB` will always be equal or (most commonly) later than `timeA`.

```
REM 12:42
set "hourA=12"
set "minA=42"

REM 12:49
set "hourB=12"
set "minB=49"

if %hourA% equ %hourB% (
  if %minA% equ %minB% (
    echo A is equal to B!
  ) else (
    echo A is NOT equal to B!
  )
)
```

I find really hard to implement the logic of checking if `timeB` is greater or equal than 30 minutes compared to `timeB` for cases like `timeA` being `12:42` and `timeB` being `13:15` where you need to check for the hours first, then the minutes and then do another check for the hours.

Any suggestions or example code would be great (I am relatively new to batch scripts). The batch script is run on Windows.

Comment: See [Find out if file is older than 4 hours in Batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928552/) . The code examples in the answers can be modified for 30 minutes difference instead of 4 hours. For time difference check within a day, multiply twice the hour with 60 and add the minute using `set /a` and compare the two integer values using `if`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "timestra=12:42"
SET "timestrb=03:01"

SET /a timediff=(1%timestrb:~0,2% - 1%timestra:~0,2%) * 60 + (1%timestrb:~-2% - 1%timestra:~-2%)
IF %timediff% lss 0 SET /a timediff+=60*24
ECHO TIME difference=%timediff%

GOTO :EOF
```

Given two valid timestrings in 24-hr format, set the time difference to 60*((100+the last HH) - (100 + the first HH)) + ((100+the last MM) - (100 + the first MM))

The `100+` is implemented by stringing `1` in front of the first/last 2 characters of the timestring. This overcomes batch's "leading 0 is octal" dictum since the leading digit in both cases is `1`.

If the result of the overall calculation is negative, then we have crossed midnight, so add an entire day's worth of minutes. This will of course only work if the distance between the two times is less than 24 hours, which is probably adequate given the presented scenario.

*then* it's a simple matter of

```
if %timediff% gtr 30 (echo more than 30) else (echo less than 30)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. When I run it by itself it works perfectly. However, when I copy paste the commands (lines 3-8) into an existing script I am getting a `0 was unexpected at this time`. Do you have any ideas why that would be?

Comment: Need to see precisely what you have in the batch and the contents of the two timestrings. You are, of course, setting the timestrings appropriately, aren't you? Also, it may depend on the precise location within the batch - if it is within a `code block` (a parenthesised series of lines) then you'd need to have `delayed expansion` in effect and use `!` in place of `%` within that pasted code (see SO using the `search` facility on the top bar for extensive documentation on `delayed expansion` if required)

Comment: Apologies, I did fix it was a parenthesis issue. Thanks