# Batscript for checking random files present in archive path or not on every day and should check for last 30 mins whether the file processed or not

Tags: batch-file

Batscript for checking random files present in archive path or not on every day and should check for last 30 mins whether the file processed or not. It should clearly check if file is processed in archive path or not for last 30 minutes. If no file processed in last 30 minutes the script should say the file does not exist. If files processed in last 30 minutes the script should say the file does exist.

Below I have script on checking the file

```
@echo off
REM CHECKING FILE FOR TODAY IN ARCHIVE
for /f %%i in ('forfiles /P G:\archive /M ce* /D +0') do set FILE=%%i
if [%FILE%] == [] (
        exit 1
) else (
        exit 0
)
```

But I'm not getting the script to check file processed for last 30 minutes. So can someone help on this query.

Comment: [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928552/find-out-if-file-is-older-than-4-hours-in-batch-file)

Comment: You should add some `echo`  to your loop to find out what is really happening.

Comment: Can you help wit the code?