# Batch cannot display both video graphics information of a laptop with two video chips

Tags: batch-file, video

I can display the video graphics information of a basic laptop, but cannot succeed if the laptop has two video chips, e.g. Intel and Nvidia. If I run my command line in command prompt window:

```
wmic.exe path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution^, CurrentVerticalResolution^, Name^ /^format:value
```

I get:

```
CurrentHorizontalResolution=
CurrentVerticalResolution=
Name=NVIDIA Quadro M1000M


CurrentHorizontalResolution=1920
CurrentVerticalResolution=1080
Name=Intel(R) HD Graphics 530
```

My code is:

```
set cmdlin="%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe path Win32_VideoController get CurrentHorizontalResolution^,CurrentVerticalResolution^,Name^/format:value"

for /F "tokens=2-4 delims== skip=2" %%i in ('%cmdlin%') do (
    for /F %%j in ("%%i") do (
    set VresH=%%i
    set VresV=%%j
    set Vname=%%k
    ECHO Res.H: %VresH% - Res.V:%VresV% - Graphics: %Vname%
    )
)
```

I have tried various echoing without success. I can see the values fed in the variables with `echo on` but not displayed...

Can somebody help to solve this and explain my errors, specially how to deal if the requested fields contains several items separated with spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be used the following batch file code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe goto OutputVideoData

echo ERROR: The WMI command-line utility wmic.exe is not installed.
echo(
echo There should not be used anymore batch files with WMIC on this computer.
echo(
echo There could be installed WMIC via Settings ^> Apps ^> Optional features.
echo(
pause
exit /B

:OutputVideoData
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH Win32_VideoController GET CurrentHorizontalResolution^,CurrentVerticalResolution^,Name /VALUE 2^>nul') do (
    if "%%G" == "CurrentHorizontalResolution" (
        set "VresH=none"
        set /A VresH=%%H 2>nul
    ) else if "%%G" == "CurrentVerticalResolution" (
        set "VresV=none"
        set /A VresV=%%H 2>nul
    ) else if "%%G" == "Name" (
        for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%I in ("%%H") do (
            set "Vname=%%I"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            echo Res.H: !VresH! - Res.V: !VresV! - Graphics: !Vname!
            endlocal
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic path /?`
- `wmic path Win32_VideoController /?`
- `wmic path Win32_VideoController get /?`

Read also:

- [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/)
- Microsoft documentation for the [Win32_VideoController class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-videocontroller)
- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)
- [Batch program with WMIC commands not working in Windows 10 Education but OK with Professional release or in CMD line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76673527/3074564)

The last referenced answer explains most of the code of the **FOR** loop capturing and processing the output of **WMIC** which is not easy to understand.

The **FOR /F** options `"tokens=2-4 delims== skip=2"` do not make sense on using **WMIC** with `/format:value` or shorter just `/VALUE` because of there is not output any line with four strings of interest separated by at least three equal signs. All three data on one line would be output by **WMIC** on omitting the option `/VALUE` respectively the option `/format:value` but that makes it very hard to process the line if nothing is output for `CurrentHorizontalResolution` and for `CurrentVerticalResolution` with the missing values replaced by spaces. The line contains just lots of spaces left to the name of the video controller if there are no values for `CurrentHorizontalResolution` and `CurrentVerticalResolution`.

`set /A VresH=%%H` and `set /A VresV=%%H` result in output of the error message `Missing operand.` to handle **STDERR** which is redirected with `2>nul` to the device **NUL** to suppress it if there is no `CurrentHorizontalResolution` and no `CurrentVerticalResolution` for the video controller. The current value of the environment variables `VresH` and `VresV` are not changed in this case which is the reason for initializing them with the string value `none`.

The main **FOR** command line can be also:

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe PATH Win32_VideoController GET CurrentHorizontalResolution^,CurrentVerticalResolution^,Name /VALUE 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe "="') do (
```

**FIND** filters out the empty lines output by **WMIC** resulting in less loop iterations.

**FIND** outputs the data in ASCII with just one byte per character instead of UTF-16 LE. But each line with data is terminated with carriage return + carriage return + line-feed (0D 0D 0A) instead of just carriage return + line-feed (0D 0A). `cmd.exe` started in background is responsible for passing the Unicode output of **WMIC** in ASCII with an extra carriage return at end of each line to **FIND**. The two `set /A` instead of just `set` and the inner **FOR** loop for removing the unwanted carriage return are still necessary with that small enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably ask WMI to only output video cards which display both a horizontal and vertical resolution. *(Obviously if one is not displaying results for those two properties, then there seems little point in displaying its information)*

```bash
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

For /F "Tokens=2,3,* EOL=N Delims=," %%G In ('
 %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_VideoController Where
 "Not CurrentHorizontalResolution Is Null And Not CurrentVerticalResolution Is Null"
 Get CurrentHorizontalResolution^, CurrentVerticalResolution^, Name /Format:CSV
 2^>NUL') Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%J In ("%%I") Do Echo %%J: %%G x %%H

Pause
```

I have split the very long single line command over lines 4-8 for readability, it does not require modification to work in your batch file. However you could use it as a single line command directly in cmd.exe, *(for testing purposes)*, if you wish.

```bash
For /F "Tokens=2,3,* EOL=N Delims=," %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe Path Win32_VideoController Where "Not CurrentHorizontalResolution Is Null And Not CurrentVerticalResolution Is Null" Get CurrentHorizontalResolution^, CurrentVerticalResolution^, Name /Format:CSV 2^>NUL') Do @For /F "Tokens=*" %J In ("%I") Do @Echo %J: %G x %H
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting an answer, but sometimes a graphic card is present without displaying H/V resolutions, and I need to record this even in this case as it is for inventory purpose (that I forgot to mention : apologize !)