# How to skip "are you sure Y/N" when deleting files in batch files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I can't for the life of me remember how to bypass the annoying prompt `are you sure? Y/N` when deleting files.

I seem to recall it was something like:

```
del C:\Test && ECHO Y
```

Comment: There is some confusion in this question, because you say that you want to delete files, but the above line does not prompt for confirmation if C:\Test is a file. It prompts only if C:\Test is a *directory*.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Use `del /F /Q` to force deletion of read-only files (`/F`) and directories and not ask to confirm (`/Q`) when deleting via wildcard.

Answer (score 77):

Add `/Q` for quiet mode and it should remove the prompt.

Answer (score 5):

I just want to add that [this nearly identical post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15148192/3546415) provides the very useful alternative of using an echo pipe if no force or quiet switch is available. For instance, I think it's the only way to bypass the Y/N prompt in this example.

```
Echo y|NETDOM COMPUTERNAME WorkComp /Add:Work-Comp
```

In a general sense you should first look at your command switches for /f, /q, or some variant thereof (for example, Netdom RenameComputer uses /Force, not /f).  If there is no switch available, then use an echo pipe.

Comment: Disadvantage: this will not work in for example German Windows editions because they expect `J` to confirm

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `powershell`, for example from `vscode` terminal, you can use `-Recurse -Force` instead:

```
del C:\Test -Recurse -Force
```

---

Note: I know that the question have `cmd` tag, but someone might come here for `powershell` or `vscode`.

Answer (score -1):

You have the following options on Windows command line:

```
net use [DeviceName [/home[{Password | *}] [/delete:{yes | no}]]
```

Try like:

```
net use H: /delete /y
```

Comment: I'm missing the relevance to deleting files?