# 'RM' is not recognized as an internal or external command while using Meteor on Windows

Tags: meteor, command-prompt

i am currently having problem with 'meteor' and i am currently new to this learning this stuff. So, after installing 'Meteor' i opened command prompt on Windows and typed :

```
meteor create goodboy
```

and then,

```
cd goodboy
```

But to delete the live and already running example app, i used :

```
rm goodboy.*
```

But the command prompt, gave this error :

> rm is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file.

Is there anyway i can fix this error, thank you.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: @DavidWeldon i am using windows 10.

Comment: So you mean `del goodboy.*`? Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607612/equivalent-of-rm-and-mv-in-windows-cmd).

Comment: Did you mean `git rm file`  ?

Answer (score 60):

Use `del` on Windows.

Also, this has nothing to do with Meteor. You can also delete a Meteor project by going to the folder and dragging it to the trash.

Answer (score 51):

If you are on windows, **git bash** may run such commands.

Comment: That works, thanks! It is so usefull for me in situation when I have scripts for linux in my project but I work on windows.

Answer (score 21):

If you are using Mac then we can simply use

`rm -f src/*`

and For windows we can use command for this is

```
 del -f "src/*"
```

Hope this works fine for you.

Answer (score 6):

Download and [Extract PortableGit](https://git-scm.com/download/win).

This has most of commonly used Linux based tools ported to windows.

Add `[PortableGit Path]\usr\bin` to PATH variable of Windows

You can also use your system's Git installation instead of PortableGit.

This should solve the problem

Comment: This was really useful! A small tip: on windows 10 default path with git utilities will be "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"

Answer (score 4):

My penny's worth.

You could potentially add rm to powershell. In your (or a) profile.ps1 (or other if your powershell is not core).

```
rm {
  del
}
```

or as an alias

```
Set-Alias rm del
```

or (and this is a tricky one), run WSL, bind the target folder and run via the linux interface.

PS: running the command via the Git Bash (MINGW64)  terminal as suggested above, did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running Git shell prompt and for some reason it doesn't have it any more. I ended up using Cygin to get it working:

https://www.cygwin.com/

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not using bash terminal. Try this..

1- Go to the folder that you want to remove its contents lets call it my-app folder.

2- Right click in the empty space, then choose get Bash here.

3- Paste the command rm -f A_folder/* (I'm about to remove the content inside A_folder folder which is a sub-folder inside my-app).

4- Hit enter.

That should remove all content from A_folder folder.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

you should add
"remove-build": "rmdir /s /q build",
"create-build": "mkdir build",
"clean": "npm run remove-build && npm run create-build",

in package.json

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are not using the Git Bash terminal but the normal command prompt.
Do try the same on the Git Bash terminal and you would not face this error anymore.

Comment: That question is not related to Git Bash at all

Answer (score 1):

Install the Unix Utils package for Windows, which includes the "rm" command. You can download it from here:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/

Add the path to the Unix Utils package to your system's environment variables.

To do this, follow these steps:

Open the Start menu and search for "Environment Variables".

Click on "Edit the system environment variables".

Click on the "Environment Variables" button.

Under "System Variables", scroll down and find "Path" and click "Edit".

Click "New" and add the path to the Unix Utils package (e.g. C:\Program Files\UnixUtils\usr\local\wbin).

Click "OK" on all windows to save your changes.

Close and reopen your terminal window to apply the changes.

Answer (score 0):

first, install linux clients for windows, I use Ubunto LTS
then install node.js and run your command again.
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/nodejs/setup-on-wsl2), you find good instructions to do it so, as well as how to install cool new Windows Terminal

Answer (score 0):

you can try use git bash because `rm` only work on it, if you are using windows default terminal maybe `del` command can work with you.