# How does one execute a command on the terminal?

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, command, command-prompt

If you can't open the link, these are the commands that I need to execute to completely delete Android Studio from my laptop.

```
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
rm -Rf /Applications/Android\ Studio.app
```

When I type the command into command prompt, it says "'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.". Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, these intructions are for MacOS, you're using Windows, in Windows to unistall AS you don't need more than installer

Answer (score 2):

`rm` is a Unix utility for removing files. If you are not using a Unix based OS like Linux or OSX, then this instruction is probably not for you. To uninstall you can simply go to `Control Panel` and uninstall as you do other programs. The `rm` alternative for Windows Command prompt is called `del`. More information on `del` is found [here](http://ss64.com/nt/del.html).

Answer (score 0):

A better Windows Command-Line equivalent of `rm -rf` is

`rmdir /s /q`

or, probably not as good, but interesting and informative

`echo y | rmdir /s`

This is discussed in the answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54637875/6505499). There, I [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15148192/6505499) the "interesting and informative" command ...

> ... used back in the day when commands did not have options to suppress confirmation messages. Simply ECHO the needed response and pipe the value into the command.