# Passing predefined parameters to bat command

Tags: batch-file, schedule

I would like to pass more than one parameters to some dos command, but don't know how to insert it in one line.

Example: If need to delete some scheduler task, will using

> `schtasks /Delete /TN "Executable"`

but above code will ask for confirm with Y | N;

How to pass Y with above code (and how to send more than one parameter if it's needed)?

Basically just want to execute command from script without doing anything at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725744.aspx#BKMK_delete

`/F` switch is for suppressing the prompt.

Comment: yes that is for those command but what with other commands -> should always be options for suppressing prompt?

Comment: @tonni - other SCHTASKS command or other windows commands? The other cases when SCHTASKS can prompt you is when the password is not provided with `/p` switch. As regards to the other windows commands - it is not a always the same and depends on the command.

Comment: @yes i mean on other windows command line rmdir (or any other) -> how to send parameters in it? (i was trying using y | echo rmdir -> or something like that). I'm searching for sending parameters to any windows command (of course if it is possible).

Comment: thnx i know that, but what i'm searching for is if there is rule on which can parameters can be send on every windows command (like first answare in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147900/how-to-supply-console-input-yes-no-as-part-of-batch-file-on-windows#)

Comment: @tonni - the standard way is `echo n|command..` but is not language settings independent , not working if the question is not `Y\N` and reduces the performance as every pipe creates a subinstance of command prompt.