# How to delete all files in a directory using batch?

Tags: batch-file, console, delete-file

I have a very simple query.
I have a folder "x" on my desktop (Windows 7),
and I want to write a Batch Program to delete all files in it. (all extensions) 
This is what I've come up with:

```
cd c:\users\admin\desktop\x\
del *.*
```

but, when I open it, the console still asks for Human input (Y/N).
What can I do to bypass this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to skip "are you sure Y/N" when deleting files in batch files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160342/how-to-skip-are-you-sure-y-n-when-deleting-files-in-batch-files)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Always use the explicit path so a flaw does not delete the current folder, whatever that may be at the time.

All visible files, silently

```
del "c:\users\admin\desktop\x\*.*?"
```

All visible files, silently using /q

```
del /q "c:\users\admin\desktop\x\*.*"
```

All visible files, including subdirectories, silently

```
del /s /q "c:\users\admin\desktop\x\*.*"
```

type `del /?` for full info.

Answer (score 1):

It's dangerous, but

```
del *?*
```

or

```
del ?*?
```

should delete as required.

Answer (score 0):

```
del /q *.*
```

See del /?
Assuming the user has proper permissions.