# How can I connect a batch file to an FTP server to delete files automatically

Tags: ftp, batch-file

I have been asked to log into a Webserver with a server IP address and administrator password and create a bat file or vb script to run and remove files in subfolders that are dated a month before today's date. This needs to be set up as a scheduled task on the server to run nightly.

How can I do this as I am a new programmer learning out things in my first job? Can anyone help me with this, please.

Comment: SO is not generally the place to ask for code. If you show us what you have tried, we will try and help. If you provided more information about the web-server you are connecting to, and tell us what has / has not worked we will endeavour to at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am asked to write a windows batch file which can automatically delete files and folders older than 30 days from FTP server's outbox.

Answer (score 0):

After a brief (one search) I found the following question on SO: [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days).

I'd recommend using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51069/863122).

In future, perhaps search to see if someone else has asked the same / a very similar question to you before asking.

So in your case you would want

`forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* -d "-30" -c "cmd /c del @path"`

Please remember to accept this answer if it answers your question.