# Delete files recursively with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008

I need to delete all files (recursively in all folders and subfolders) based on their **last access** time.

I was looking at Stack Overflow post *[Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days/51069#51069)* that suggested this answer:

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* -d <number of days> -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

However, this deletes files based on last modified time, not last access time.

Also, is there a way to save the command in a script file so I can just doubleclick it to run?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem -recurse` to get all the files, you can then pipe them to the `where-object` commandlet to filter out the directories and use the `LastAccessTime` property to filter based on that attribute. Then you pipe the result to a foreach-object that executes the delete command.

It ends up looking like this. Note the use of Get-Date, to get all files updated since the start of the year, replace with your own date:

```
get-childitem C:\what\ever -recurse | where-object {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastAccessTime -gt (get-date "1/1/2012"))} | foreach-object { del $_ }
```

Or to use some common aliases to shorten everything:

```
dir C:\what\ever -recurse | ? {-not $_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.LastAccessTime -gt (get-date "1/1/2012"))} | % { del $_ }
```

Comment: I would like to add, if you are looking for things that are 7 days old, you can use the `(Get-Date).AddDays(-7)` to do a more variable date.

Answer (score 4):

As an aside, this is how you'd do the same (get files only) in PowerShell 3.0:

```
$old = Get-Date "1/1/2012"

Get-ChildItem C:\what\ever -File -Recurse | 
Where-Object {$_.LastAccessTime -gt $old} | 
Remove-Item -Force
```