# windows batch script to svn delete set of folders

Tags: windows, svn, batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

Suppose there are 15 folders committed in svn (each name starting with `folder_`).
**How can I run `svn delete` on all the folders which were created on or before a specific date?**

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rohan

Comment: Welcome to `stackoverflow`, check out my edit to your post. Hopefully that will help you format your posts in a more productive manner in the future!

Comment: Is this a recursive job? If not, then I'll suggest to go and manually delete them from SVN. Better to have some discretion with SVN as you would not want accidently deteting a folder and then reverting it back. Or, you can give some more explanation of the issue above and what's your progress till now...

Answer (score 0):

I found this that might help you in your quest. Its not svn delete but it will get the job done.
[Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all sub folders named **.svn** 
then create batch file with this content:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('dir /s /b /a:d *.svn') do (
rd /s /q "%%i"
)
```

save it in a file **del_All_Dot_SVN_Folders.cmd** . Run it. Your done.

Thanks to http://www.axelscript.com/2008/03/11/delete-all-svn-files-in-windows/

Remember the above code has .svn whereas the code in the link has only *svn so its better
to have the .svn to not accidentally have undesired effect.