# How to create a windows service to schedule some task like delete the files on a certain folder?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

Hi i am relatively new to windows service. I want to create a schedule task that will go through certain folder like c://dev/ and delete the files that are created between some date/time. How can i achieve this?Any help really appriciated...

Comment: Do you really need to make a service for this?  A simple batch file run by the Windows Scheduler should do the job.

Comment: Do you want to create windows service that does something (i.e. delete files) OR you want to delete files (i.e. by using windows service) - these questions are very different, but it is unclear which one you wanted to ask.

Comment: Sorry Alexei I want to create windows service that deletes files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this for 'forfiles' command: [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Then you can store a command of your wish into a .bat file and set Windows Task Scheduler to run that file.

If you want to do it using Windows Services, check this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/7224/deleting-a-file-after-7-days-using-windows-services.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer for its not what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: thanks for the answer...managed to do this way

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a **custom scheduler** from a windows service, you can try out the [Quartz](http://quartz-scheduler.org/overview) open source scheduling service library. You can then define [CRON Triggers](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger) to fire as and when you need. I have used this in a windows service developed in C# and its excellent. The [tutorials](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/) will quickly get you up and running.

For the windows service itself, you can have a look at the article by @mostruash above or even [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C). You can easily customize the base templates as per your wishes.