# Quartz.net windows service core concepts

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, quartz.net

I want to work with job scheduling and browsing on the internet I saw that Quartz.Net is a good option for it. Many blogs show that a windows service must be initialized and my question is: is it always necessary to start a windows service and embed it to run a job scheduler? Is there a way to run a job scheduler without using a windows service, I ask this because I have a access to a hosting that has only a web panel and I don't think it will let start a windows service.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Thanks Sergio. and congrats on your first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, a alternative to writing a simple windows service, is to use the inbuilt windows task scheduler, if you have administrative permissions on the machine you would like to configure. To configure a task in Task Scheduler, have a look at the following [Microsoft Article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-sg/windows7/schedule-a-task)

Working with a windows service is very simple too, a good starting point is as shown below

[Walkthrough: Creating a Windows Service Application in the Component Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I have worked on Quartz.NET and recommend it highly. The best resources that I used when working with Quartz are as given in the following [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15353584/1012641).

Quartz can also be used in a ASP.NET web application

- [How to use Quartz.net with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1356789/1012641)
- [Quartz.net setup in an asp.net website](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3245975/1012641)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, I could work with Quartz.Net in my local machine but I cannot do it in the hosting I have, I mean the web panel just can configure databases, emails and so on, it's very restricted no remote access no ssh, remote desktop, just a web panel, so I don't think I could create a windows service or work with Task Scheduler

Comment: I would but I only have 8 of reputation, when I have enough I will do it, thank you for the answer