# Batch file logic to delete files based on date in filename

Tags: batch-file

I now have a seemingly innocuous requirement to be put in a .bat file ,I am dealing with Batch code for the first time ...found a page   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days) that deals with something similar but it takes the modified date as reference.

In a particular folder X , Delete all files older than N days by parsing through their file name. 
where file name format is Name_YYYYMMDD.log

But note :
1. Do not want the last modified date as reference (log might have been accessed/modified by other programs/apps)
2.No permission to install other utilities.

EDIT :

- The FORFILES command worked perfectly well for this job (but only drawback is it takes'modified date' as reference)
- The script below by Aacini works fine after tweaking it to specifications.
- Due to additional conditions which further complicates the entire scenario ,we have decided to move away from batch and do it in Powershell or AutoIT.

Thanks!.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please [edit] your question to include all relevant code.

Comment: What is the maximum number of days you would go back?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Batch file below convert file date to Julian Day Number, that is a sequential number of days, and use it to know how many days old is each one. The number of days to delete files is given in the parameter.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get Julian Day Number of today's date
rem The assumed format is MM/DD/YYYY, change C-A-B order in accordance with your locale
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set todayDate=%%c%%a%%b
)
call :DateToJDN %todayDate% todayJDN=

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.*') do (
   call :DateToJDN %%b fileJDN=
   set /A daysOld=todayJDN - fileJDN
   if !daysOld! gtr %1 (
      echo File "%%a_%%b.%%c" is !daysOld! days old
   )
)
goto :EOF

:DateToJDN yyyymmdd jdn=
set yyyymmdd=%1
set /A yyyy=%yyyymmdd:~0,4%, mm=1%yyyymmdd:~4,2% %% 100, dd=1%yyyymmdd:~6% %% 100
set /A a=(mm-14)/12, %2=(1461*(yyyy+4800+a))/4+(367*(mm-2-12*a))/12-(3*((yyyy+4900+a)/100))/4+dd-32075
exit /B
```

Test this program and change the `echo File "%%a_%%b.%%c" ...` command by the desired `del "%%a_%%b.%%c"` one.

Reference: http://www.hermetic.ch/cal_stud/jdn.htm#comp

Comment: It worked fine after some tweaking  but the requirements changed again :( and we are moving away from batch to Powershell/AutoIT.  Thanks!.

Comment: @spyky_42: May I ask you to give me some points for my answer? Perhaps an upvote? Thanks...

Comment: I'll give you an upvote for him :) I can't believe how close the code I was writing for this is compared to yours. Nearly the same with a few minor differences that you handled better anyway.

Comment: @Aacini Could you explain your answer and add where i can add the directory or the target folder path. TIA

Answer (score 1):

here you have, it will delete file e.g. 20180105.log on January 5, it's working with date format YYYY-MM-DD,
for date format MM/DD/YYYY change this delims=/ and check "echo todayDate !todayDate!" for manipulating a b c

```
cls
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %%a in ("%date%") do (
   set todayDate=%%a%%b%%c
)

rem echo todayDate !todayDate!

for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=_." %%a in ('dir /B /A-D *.*') do (

   set /A daysOld=todayDate - "%%a"

   if !daysOld! EQU 0 (
      echo deleting.. %%a.%%b
      echo del %%a.%%b
   )
)
```

Test it and change the `echo del %%a.%%b` to `del %%a.%%b`