# How to delete files with specific names in windows 10 using batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, del

Could you please help me with a command for batch file to delete the files with Name of the file.

I need to delete the files which are older than 6 months according to their File name. I need to schedule the script in Task scheduler, So it will delete the files in specific location every day which are older than 6 months from current date according to their file name.

Location of files:

```
K:\Bck
```

File Names:

```
Backup_2020-10-22.txt
Backup_2020-10-21.txt
Backup_2019-09-16.txt
Backup_2018-05-17.txt
Backup_2017-04-16.txt
```

Comment: This topic has been posted many times here on SO. I suggest you do a search?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Gerhard, i have searched many sites but could not find the correct solution. The commands which i found were deleting the files which are older than 6 months according to their Modified/Created date and not with File Name. My requirement is different and need to delete according to the File name which is older than 6 months.

Comment: which to reiterate what @Gerhard has already said, [there are a multitude of questions on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+delete+file+name+older) with answers explaining how to achieve what your duplicate question asks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Batch file logic to delete files based on date in filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613625/batch-file-logic-to-delete-files-based-on-date-in-filename)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version of [`Aacini's`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613625/batch-file-logic-to-delete-files-based-on-date-in-filename) post, from back in 2013. I only amended it to use `powershell` to get today's date, instead of using the locale specific `%date%` variable and some changes to accomodate your environment. So I take no credit for this whatsoever.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "K:\Bck"
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMdd'}"') do set todayDate=%%i
call :DateToJDN %todayDate% todayJDN=

for /F "tokens=1-4* delims=_-" %%a in ('dir /B /A-D "Backup_*-*-*.txt"') do (
   call :DateToJDN %%b%%c%%~nd fileJDN=
   set /A daysOld=todayJDN - fileJDN
   if !daysOld! gtr 180 (
      echo File "%%a_%%b-%%c-%%d" is !daysOld! days old
      del "%%a_%%b-%%c-%%d" /Q
   )
)
popd
goto :eof

:DateToJDN yyyymmdd jdn=
set yyyymmdd=%1
set /A yyyy=%yyyymmdd:~0,4%, mm=1%yyyymmdd:~4,2% %% 100, dd=1%yyyymmdd:~6% %% 100
set /A a=(mm-14)/12, %2=(1461*(yyyy+4800+a))/4+(367*(mm-2-12*a))/12-(3*((yyyy+4900+a)/100))/4+dd-32075
exit /B
```

This will NOT yet delete anything. It will simply echo the commands to the screen. If you are sure the `echo`'d results resemble what you want, you can remove the `echo` from the line `echo del "%%a_%%b_%%c_%%d" /Q`

You also need to set your days accordingly in the line `if !daysOld! gtr 180 (`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I am getting result as below, i removed echo from del command line, but that file is not deleting. Do you have any suggestion.

Log:

File "Backup_2019-10-21.txt__" is 708 days old

Comment: I am not getting any error message, but it is not deleting the files which are older than 180 days.

Also i am getting Delimiters underscore "txt__" at the end of file name, Why i am getting like that. "Backup_2019-10-21.txt__"?

Comment: Yes, Sorry i have checked the format and updated now. It was wrong before. I'll test your latest update and get back to you. Thanks for your kind help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Thank you very much Gerhard, The script is working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Remember to change your script accordingly when your file layouts change. These scripts are specific to your formats.

Comment: Thanks for your help, may i know how to close this Query? this is resolved by you.