# Delete files with batch job

Tags: batch-file, file-io

I want to delete .txt extention files in my computer every 30 days using batch script...

files name are like:

```
filename_20082013.txt
filename_21082013.txt
filename_22082013.txt
filename_23082013.txt
```

Comment: Ok, and what have you done so far? Can we see the script you're working on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows:

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* -d <number of days> -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

So:

```
forfiles -p "C:\your\path" -s -m *.txt -d -30 -c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Source: [Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

This will delete files that are at least 30 days old (you can change it to any number)...now you need to schedule this task to run every 30 days:

**You can use Windows Task Scheduler:**

[image: You can use Windows Task Scheduler]

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/schedule-a-task

**Or you can use StreamServe Task Scheduler:**

[image: Or you can use StreamServe Task Scheduler]

http://streamshare.streamserve.com/Articles/Article/?articleId=424

Answer (score 2):

suggestion for approx. 30 days, run the command on the first day of the month:

```
del *072013.txt
```

for this month and

```
del *082013.txt
```

for the next month.
The command also works in a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the "Task Scheduler" on Windows, or a cron job on Unix.