# Move files based on a date string in the file name batch

Tags: date, pdf, batch-file

I have directory that is continuously being updated with pdf files. The file names look like this:

```
0001_2014_02_14_000000001_018_001_000.pdf

0001_2014_02_14_000000002_018_002_000.pdf

0001_2014_02_15_000000003_018_001_000.pdf

0001_2014_02_15_000000004_018_002_000.pdf
```

How would I create a batch file that will parse the date (character place 6) and move the files to a directory called `d:\send`.  To make it more complex I need to subtract 3 days from today's date and only move those files.  BTW the modified date of the files won't work. The correct date is the date in the file name.

example:
today is 2/21/2014
find the files that have a prefix of `0001_2014_02_18_??????????.pdf` and send them to `d:\send`

Of course today's date will change daily and this will be scheduled to run everyday.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This can probably be done using this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days?rq=1

Comment: @preetsangha That link only shows examples for files `older` than a given figure, not exactly equal to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test this on some sample files:

```
@echo off
set day=-3
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
move "????_%yyyy%_%mm%_%dd%_*.pdf" "d:\send"
pause
```

Comment: I see where you are going with this.  It should work but I am getting "A duplicate file exists or the file cannot be found."  Checking the paths and file names now.  Stand by.