# Rename Files Older Than 1 day

Tags: batch-file, windows-console

I want to rename all file in a specified folder ending with .txt to .csv that are older then 1 day. I have the following that will get me all files ending with .txt and rename them to .csv

```
For /R %1 %%G IN (*.txt) DO ren "%%G" "%%~nG.csv"
```

The part I am struggling with is only renaming the files that are older then a day. I am looking for a solution that will work despite the date format that may be set up on a system.

Comment: what windows version are you using? i am asking this because forfiles.exe provides the useful switch which could help to build a solution to your problem

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file to delete files older than N days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Comment: @AcidJunkie I am developing on Windows 7 but would like the script to be able to run on Windows Server 2008,2012, and Windows Vista,7,8.1

Comment: @KevinKunderman hm okay. still you could use forfile.exe, but then you have to assemble the current date so it could be used for the /d argument. On Windows 2012 / Windows 8, forfile.exe allows to specify the file age in days. Is vbscript not an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use "forfiles". The code would be:

```
forfiles /m "*.txt" /c "cmd /c Ren @fname.txt *.csv" /d -01
```

That will rename all .txt files to .csv files.

## Edit

Ren *.txt was changed to @fname.txt

Comment: Is forfiles native to many windows os's or would I have to install something to get this to work across the board?

Comment: Vista upwards it is available for

Comment: This renames all files  with the .tmp extension seems to ignor the older then 1 day rule

Comment: Converting .txt to .tmp or vice versa?

Comment: Really? I tried it out a couple of times on widows 8. I see you're operating on windows 7, which may be a cause. Does it just rename all of the files with the .txt extension?

Comment: Do you want 24 hours and older, or is the date not being equal to the current date sufficient for your needs?

Comment: @Behavior What it seems to be doing is that if it finds one .txt file that is older then a day it will rename the extension on all of them.

Comment: Figured it out instead of Ren *.txt *.csv" I had to uses the FNAME variable to just rename the file it found.  Ren @FNAME.txt *.csv"