# Delete files between two dates server 2003 commandline

Tags: batch-file, command-line

Can somebody tell me the best way to delete a series of files between April 1, 2014 and April 17, 2014 on Windows server 2003 command line

Comment: Have you tried anything (including a search here) in order to do so? This is not a "Here are my specs. Please write the code. I'll stop back later to pick it up." site.

Comment: Tried doing a for files and for /f

Comment: Try doing a search for (including the brackets) `[batch-file] delete files older`. The very first hit is [Batch file to delete files older than N days](http://stackoverflow.com/q/51054), which gives you half of the answer. It should be pretty easy then to modify to add the other half (or at least give you a place to start trying to do so).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PowerShell oneliner will do the trick.  You can remove the back-ticks and put the code all on one line if you want.

```
Get-ChildItem C:\data\*.* | `
Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -gt '4/1/14' -AND $_.lastwritetime -lt '4/17/14'} | `
Remove-Item
```

I found a shorter version of the script [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/06/17/powertip-find-files-modified-during-a-date-range-by-using-powershell.aspx).  I prefer to use the full Powershell cmdlet names though.

Comment: Thanks but can't use powershell