# PHP Deleting a file 24 hours after being uploaded

Tags: php, web

I've made a simple script that allows users to upload html files to a web directory on my server. However, I'd like it so each file is deleted after 24 hours of being on my server. 24 hours for each file, not 24 hours for the entire directory. Here is my code so far... Thank you for your help. :)

```
<?php 
 $target = "users/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 

 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)
 && ($_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] == "html")) 
 {
 echo "File: " . $_FILES["uploaded"]["name"] . "<br />";
 echo "Type: " . $_FILES["uploaded"]["type"] . "<br />";
 echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["uploaded"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
 echo "Location: /users/" . $_FILES["uploaded"]["name"]; 
 } 

 else {
 echo "Sorry, " . $_FILES["uploaded"]["name"] . " is not a valid HTML document. Please try again.";
 unlink . $_FILES["uploaded"]["name"];
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Store the upload time and filepath/name in the db and run a cron job every 24 hrs

Comment: Can you specify the server operating system?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Cron` to execute this script every 10 minutes (better 30 or 60)

```
$Time=time();
foreach(glob('/users/*') as $file){
    if(filemtime($file)+60*60*24<$Time){
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not fullproof, but it gives an idea..

```
foreach(glob("/users/YOUR_USER/*") as $file) {
   $file = "/users/YOUR_USER/".$file;
   if ((time() - filectime($file)) >= 86400) {
      // delete me
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a Windows server then run a batch file using Windows Scheduler:
[Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Otherwise, just set up a CRON job.

Answer (score 0):

Include following script at the end of your script. Don't forget to replace `/var/www/uploads/` with correct path. Other wise all files will be removed in different place.

```
$files=shell_exec('find /var/www/uploads/ -mmin +1440');
$file = explode("\n",$files);
if(isset($file) && is_array($file))
{
    foreach($file as $val)
    {
        @unlink($val);
    }
}
```

The above code will work on Linux/UNIX based hosting.

- "shell_exec" will execute linux command and return the out put
- "find -mmin -1440" is looking for files older than 1 day or 1440
  minutes
- First line "/var/www/uploads/" path need to be replaced with full
  path of the directory.
- Unlink have "@" sign to avoid warning if the file not exists there.
- As this is powerful linux based command verify the paths correctly.

Comment: I've decided to go with this one. Thank you very much! I am yet to test it as it will take 24 hours but it seems good to me. Do you know how I could restrict the file uploads to only HTML? Thanks!

Comment: I've got the file restriction down now but it has stopped putting the uploaded files into the directory. What's wrong?

Comment: is it linux based system?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I'm using bluehost.