# Recursively search sub-folders and delete all files in sub-folders older than 6-months

Tags: batch-file, command-line, vbscript, delete-file, dir

We have a directory structure like this

..\Document Name_archive\YYYY\MonthName

so for example we have many sub-folders (within different *document name* folders) called \2014\January ... etc

We'd like to remove all the folders **and their contents** that have a created date older than 180 days.

We'd prefer to just use a batch file script, but perhaps a VBScript is better if we need to recursively search.

What's the best way please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a VBScript solution that uses a recursive function.

```
' Global FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Start at the root
DoFolder "c:\document_root\"

' Recursive function
Sub DoFolder(strFolder)

    With objFSO.GetFolder(strFolder)

        For Each objFile In .Files
            If objFile.DateCreated < Date - 180 Then objFile.Delete
        Next

        For Each objFolder In .SubFolders
            DoFolder objFolder.Path
        Next

        ' Checked every file and subfolder. If this folder is empty, remove it...
        If .Files.Count = 0 Then If .SubFolders.Count = 0 Then .Delete

    End With

End Sub
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days?rq=1) for a batch example using the `forfiles` command.