# remove xml tags from file with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have file:

```
<tag1>text1</tag1><tag2>text2</tag2>
<tag3>text3</tag3>
```

I want to be :

```
text1
text2
text3
```

with new line for every text.Is it possible with batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could evaluate the file as XML and output each leaf node's `nodeValue`.

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "xmlfile=test.xml"

@cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%xmlfile%" & goto :EOF

@end

var xmlDoc = WSH.CreateObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM'),
    fso = WSH.CreateObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    xmlFile = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1);

xmlDoc.loadXML('<root>' + xmlFile.ReadAll() + '</root>');

xmlFile.Close();
xmlDoc.async = false;

if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode) {
   var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
   WSH.Echo(myErr.reason);
} else {
    function walker(node) {
        for (var nodes=node.childNodes, i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) {
            if (nodes[i].hasChildNodes) {
                walker(nodes[i]);
            } else {
                WSH.Echo(nodes[i].nodeValue);
            }
        }
    }
    walker(xmlDoc.documentElement);
}
```

Comment: this work better ,but I not understand code. How java code work from batch?

Comment: It's JScript.  It's a hybrid script.  Batch evaluates the first line as false and continues to the next line.  When the batch thread reaches the `cscript` line, the script is re-evaluated as JScript.  JScript evaluates the first line as false and skips to `@end`.  When the JScript reaches the end of the script, it returns control to batch.  Since the next instruction in batch is `goto :EOF`, the batch script then ends.  [See this page](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433) for more examples of hybrid batch scripts.

Comment: hello rojo .other my question also has jscript but is diferent : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410139/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-hours-or-minutes ? thanks

Comment: [The referenced script](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/FileTimeFilerJS.bat) is another style of hybrid using a multiline comment (the `/*` and `*/`) to delimit the batch section.  It is similar to [the Hybrid2.bat example](https://gist.github.com/davidruhmann/5199433).  The hybrid formats are only slightly different.  But the language npocmaka uses is JScript.NET, which is not the same language as JScript.  His uses `jsc.exe` as an interpreter.  Mine uses `cscript.exe`.

Answer (score 3):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q28433530.txt) DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 CALL :process
)
)>newfile.txt
GOTO :EOF

:process

:procloop
FOR /f "tokens=1,2,3*delims=<>" %%i IN ("%line%") DO IF "%%j" neq "" ECHO(%%j&IF "%%l" neq "" SET "line=%%l"&GOTO procloop

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q28433530.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

This would probably do what you appear to want, provied you've given us realistic representative data.

Comment: ＋1 I thought about doing something like this, but decided on parsing over scraping. Scraping is boring. But yours is less boring than mine would've been. I like your solution for recursing multiple tags on one line.  Warning though: valid XML with a root tag and / or sections will result in lines of "ECHO is off." ending up in `newfile.txt`.