# How to delete files older than X hours or minutes?

Tags: batch-file

How to delete files older than X hours or minutes?

I have a batch file that delete files in a directory which is older than 1 day, but I need for minutes and hours.

```
REM Remove files older than 1 day
forfiles /p "C:\Users\Username\Downloads" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -1
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Find out if file is older than 4 hours in Batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928552/find-out-if-file-is-older-than-4-hours-in-batch-file).

Answer (score 4):

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%# in ('FileDateFilterJS.bat  "." -hh -5') do (
    echo deleting  "%%~f#"
    echo del /q /f "%%~f#"
)

pause
```

Replace "." with your Working directory
 Here is the FileDateFilterJS.bat given by **[npocmaka](https://github.com/npocmaka)**

https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/FileTimeFilerJS.bat

**IF** this does not work give the below code a shot although the above code works for me the below code will work for number of days and not hours.

```
forfiles -p "C:\what\ever" -s -m *.* /D -<number of days> /C "cmd /c del @path"
```

[Batch file to delete files older than N days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

> Note that if you want files OLDER than 10 days, you need to specify -d
>   "-10". -ve means "older than", +ve means "newer than". You can also
>   specify DDMMYY or -DDMMYY format as the parameter to -d.
>
> If you don't have forfiles installed on your machine, copy it from any
>   Windows Server 2003 to your Windows XP machine at %WinDir%\system32.
>   This is possible since the EXE is fully compatible between Windows
>   Server 2003 and Windows XP.

[Batch file to delete files older than N hours or minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28410139/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-hours-or-minutes)

This might help too.

Hope I helped.

Comment: I don't need for N days i need for hours or minutes!

Comment: and where i insert the location of file?[directory] rg:"C:\Users\Username\Downloads"

Comment: "." replace it with "your location"

Comment: it's not working just automatically open cmd nothing more!

Comment: Did you download the attached bat file from https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/.net/FileTimeFilerJS.bat

Comment: it's a long script and it's difficult to understand that there aren't any simple script like that?  [forfiles /p "C:\Users\Username\Downloads" /s /m *.* /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -1]

Comment: That's all the research I could do. It works perfect for me.

Comment: then it's useless for me because i need a batch file that delete files under a directory that are old more than 1 hour! i don't need for specific file!

Answer (score 1):

The tools/answers posted by Rishav should help you though they are not so heavily tested (the line posted by him should work though).To bulletproof your query you might need some fre more command line switches.
Here's an example with the [**WSH version of filetimefilter**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/FileTimeFilterJS.bat):

```
call filetimefilterjs.bat "C:\somedir" -hh -10 -direction after  -filetime created
```

this will show the files newer than 10 hours in `c:\somedir` (it is not recursive).Hope this will help.