# What is wrong in this batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a script in batch file that do the following:

1. Locate all folders with the name "Mdata" in "C:\Project".
2. Delete all folders in "Mdata" that older than 30 days.

My code is:

```
@echo off
for  /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\project\" ^|findstr /e /i "\Mdata"') do (
@echo "%%~a"
setlocal
set target=%%a
set days=-30
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%G in (
  `forfiles /p "%target%" /c "cmd /c if /i @isdir == true echo @path" /d %days% 2^>nul`
  ) do rd /s /q "%%~G"
  endlocal & exit /b
)
pause
```

The first task to locate all "Mdata" folders working well.
but the delete dosen't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Batch file to delete files older than N days](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take care of it.
I simplified your script a bit to remove the inner `FOR` loop since you can just perform your deletion from withing the `FORFILES` command.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set days=-30
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\project\" ^|findstr /e /i "\Mdata"') do (
    echo "%%~a" 
    forfiles /p "%%~a" /d %days% /c "cmd /c if /i @isdir==true echo @path & rd /s /q @path"
)

ENDLOCAL
pause
```

The reason your script wasn't working is because you did not have delayed expansion enabled, so the `target` and `days` would not be usable for your inner `FOR` loop. As it stands though, you don't need this functionality enabled for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working good. Now I'm trying to send the path (String) of all directories prior delete to Excel file: Does it work if I add: 'echo @path>>path_Deleted.xls' in the 'forfiles' loop. @Jason Faulkner.

Comment: The issue is : it send to Excel the "Mdata" Folders and not the deleted folders string! Where should I put the 'echo "%%~a">>path_Deleted.xls' inorder to see the deleted folders name? @Jason Faulkner.

Comment: @YWATFA - Excel is a binary format so you won't be able to send the output directly to XLS format.