# Forfiles command for windows XP

Tags: batch-file

Followed the question: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Batch+file+to+delete+files+older+than+N+days -

I changed it in order to work in another machine that has windows XP:

```
forfiles -p"%%~a" -s -m*.* -d%days% -c"cmd /c if /i @isdir==true echo Deleting... @path & echo @path>>C:\Jobfolder\Folders_that_deleted.txt & rd /s /q @path"
```

and it is not working.

Comment: `it is not working` is a bit vague. It results into a shutdown, a bluescreen, it does nothing or what?

Comment: Yes It does nothing. My script is just two loops. The 'forfiles' is inside 'for'. As I said above... I copied the 'forfiles.exe' to C:\windows\system32 in the OLD machine that have windows XP. The syntax of the (XP forfiles) I took from this site from the qestion: "Batch file to delete files older than N days" as I mentioned. I appreciated your help! Thanks.

Comment: forfiles -p[path] -s -m*.* -c"CMD /C if @ISDIR==TRUE echo Deleting...@PATH & echo @PATH>>C:\Jobfolder\Folders_that_deleted.txt & rd /s /q @PATH" -d%days% - This is the correct syntax. and the problem solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(Answered in the comments and question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [What is the appropriate action when the answer to a question is added to the question itself?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que) )

The OP wrote:

> I downloaded `Forfiles.exe` from that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days?s=1|10.4294) and copied it to C:\windows\system32. my `forfiles` is (it works perfect in Windows 7):
>
> ```
> forfiles /p "%%~a" /d %days% /c "cmd /c if /i @isdir==true echo Deleting... @path & echo @path>>C:\Jobfolder\Folders_that_deleted.txt & rd /s /q @path"
> ```